# Stack Overflow question checklist

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

My [earlier blog post](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) on how to write a good question is pretty long, and I suspect that even when I refer people to it, often they don't bother reading it. So here's a short list of questions to check after you've written a question (and to think about before you write the question):

1. Have you done some research before asking the question? <sup>1</sup>
2. Have you explained what you've already tried to solve your problem?
3. Have you specified which language and platform you're using, including version number where relevant?
4. If your question includes code, have you written it as a short but complete program? <sup>2</sup>
5. If your question includes code, have you checked that it's correctly formatted? <sup>3</sup>
6. If your code doesn't compile, have you included the exact compiler error?
7. If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?
8. If your program throws an exception, have you included the exception, with both the message and the stack trace?
9. If your program produces different results to what you expected, have you stated what you expected, why you expected it, and the actual results?
10. If your question is related to anything locale-specific (languages, time zones) have you stated the relevant information about your system (e.g. your current time zone)?
11. Have you checked that your question looks reasonable in terms of formatting?
12. Have you checked the spelling and grammar to the best of your ability? <sup>4</sup>
13. Have you read the whole question to yourself carefully, to make sure it makes sense and contains enough information for someone coming to it without any of the context that you already know?

If the answer to any of these questions is "no" you should take the time to fix up your question before posting, by going through this list. I realize this may seem like a lot of effort, but it will help you to get a useful answer as quickly as possible; and you might even solve your problem yourself in the process! <sup>5</sup>

Don't forget that you're basically asking other people to help you out of the goodness of their heart - it's up to you to do all you can to make that as simple as possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If you went from "something's not working" to "asking a question" in less than 10 minutes, you probably haven't done enough research. This should include things like normal web searches (e.g. for an error message you're receiving), checking the documentation, debugging (particularly for exceptions) and searching on Stack Overflow itself for similar questions.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Ideally anyone answering the question should be able to copy your code, paste it into a text editor, compile it, run it, and observe the problem. Console applications are good for this - unless your question is directly about a user interface aspect, prefer to write a short console app. Remove anything not directly related to your question, but keep it complete enough to run.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Try to avoid code which makes users scroll horizontally. You may well need to change how you split lines from how you have it in your IDE. Take the time to make it as clear as possible for those trying to help you.</sub>

<sup>4</sup> <sub>I realize that English isn't the first language for many Stack Overflow users. We're not looking for perfection - just some effort. If you know your English isn't good, see if a colleague or friend can help you with your question before you post it.</sub>

<sup>5</sup> <sub>This is a bit like [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)</sub>

Comment: a gentle version of [WSOiN](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not "What stack Overflow is Not - 10K-only link")? (10k only) :)

Comment: @gnat: Yes - more focused on getting the right information in the question.

Comment: I love this. I do. But I think it's still far too long for the entry level folks.

Comment: `I realize this may seem like a lot of effort, but it will help you to get a useful answer as quickly as possible` More to the point, it's only right for the person looking for help to put in that effort, rather than expecting us to do it for them! I guess much of the time they don't even realise or understand that that is what we're doing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Too long, or too demanding? That's the thing - this is *all* for the ultimate of the person asking the question. I've been accused of being "elitist" as if any of these items is only feasible for expert programmers. I don't know how we get over that hurdle.

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, neither do I.

Comment: @JonSkeet The first line, `Have you done some research before asking the question` IMPO need some extra tips to the new users, some steps that need to be made as: 1. Google the error code, 2. Look inside the SO for similar keywords with the error or the issue, look on other standard sites for sample code, or other samples 3. After have find all possible or similar solutions, then to try to solve it alone, then come and make a question and show what have try on that part. I say that because they do not even search on SO for similar questions on many cases.

Comment: @Aristos: I'll edit the footnote a little.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suggest one more line after the first. `Do you have debug your program line by line trying to locate the bug/error ?` Many negative votes go to that kind of questions, that have a lot of code that actually is need to debug by the user to locate where is the null, or what value is get and how.

Comment: @Aristos: I don't understand your proposal, I'm afraid. Perhaps something on the "exception" point?

Comment: @JonSkeet This question is a sample of what I try to say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600369/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-a-stored-procedure   a step by step debug on the code will give him the answer. Also on the book "Writing Solid Code" Steve Maguire it says the same trick to locate bugs.

Comment: @Aristos: Okay, that sounds like an edit to the "research" step then. Will edit.

Comment: I'm afraid that both the length of the list *and* the length of each item (not to speak of the footnotes) will still turn away those who would most need it. It should be even more distilled to a smaller number of short items.

Comment: Those who don't try to do research or put efforts will neither read this Checklist nor read FAQ.

Comment: @Hardik that's not the point. It's a helpful resource that we can point people to when their question gets closed.

Comment: Re the length - I think it's very condensed already, I can see little to no flab left to cut away in Jon's list. Maybe a format like the one we used for *What Stack Overflow is not* might work? ie. having a short, simplified heading (like those Joachim suggests below) in the question, and the detailed entries as separate answers... but that would arguably make things even *more* complex. Hmm.

Comment: @Tshepang: I don't see how "If this gets deleted, so be it" is "inflammatory" - I was simply acknowledging that some people might feel it's too close to the "What Stack Overflow is not" post, and vote to delete it. If that happened, I wasn't going to kick up a fuss. The intention was to be the opposite of inflammatory... still, it seems like it isn't needed, so I'm happy not to roll back the edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe my choice of word is bad; the point is that the comment was not positive/constructive

Comment: @Aristos I did not mean to offend; each edit I do is to help improve a post, but I guess I fail in some eyes sometimes.

Comment: I find myself editing tags a lot, perhaps you can include "did you apply the most relevant tags on your question?"

Comment: Some, if not most of this information should be added to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page in one form or another. I find myself having a hard time to decide where to point users. The *How to Ask* page is lacking in information while this post is a bit too verbose.

Comment: Why can't I ask for opinions, if I want to know whats available for functional programming, where do I go? I do not want to know what functional programming languages are available but people are using, and coming to a place like this would allow that to be answered fast, and help make my decision. Things like "Whats the best face recon library out there?" also are helpful, and if I can't ask here where would I go to do so?

Comment: @Oakcool: I don't know what appropriate alternative there is, but a lack of alternatives doesn't make an opinion-based question welcome on SO.

Comment: This is a long list, Jon, and I think it might be less intimidating to the newbies if it were presented as some kind of flow chart.  Pictures are always less scary, somehow, and stuff like "does your question include code?" and "does your code compile?" is just screaming to be drawn inside little diamond shapes.  Next time I get a spare minute, I might have a go at drawing this.

Comment: I would like to mention that one can attache the screenshot or image of his/her question to make it understand easily by others.

Comment: @AnkurPandya: Sometimes that's useful, but far too often people take screenshots of code, which is far less useful than including the code itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have intended to read [your article](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) however the web site is not working. ___The resource cannot be found___

Comment: @mohacs: I've edited the link now, thanks - my blog has moved.

Comment: Sadly, I think this list will not help much. The kind of people who would take the time to read this list would also read the Help Centre and examine existing questions. They are already likely to post an acceptable question. The newcomers who post rubbish can't be bothered to read instructions because they want their question answered *right now*.

Comment: @Raedwald: Well, it at least allows me to direct someone who's already posted something somewhat rubbish to a fairly concise list - it gives them an easy second chance.

Comment: @DavidWallace:  +100 for flowchart suggestion.  It *must* be somewhat entertaining as well thoug (think xkcd).  The type of new users that post poor questions aren't going to read a list (maybe if its under 3 items).  Give them a worthwhile visual to peruse, and we might actually make some progress!

Comment: See [pre-flight question screening checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item); the idea was to be adaptive about which ones are picked and narrow it down to 3 or so...gather some efficacy statistics, crowdsource the tips.  These could be in there.  Horizontal scrolling code is definitely a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Thank you for this. It will help me greatly in asking future questions. I've marked it as a favorite.

Comment: Should this be promoted to FAQ status? It seems *highly* relevant.

Comment: @JonSkeet You of all people *elitist?* Elite, 100%. Elitist, 0%.

Answer (score 211):

I think to actually get the *average asker of bad questions* to read those items, they need to be fewer and shorter. This means sacrificing precision.

Something like this, maybe:

- Did you google your question (going beyond the first page)?
- What have you tried?
- What language/IDE are you using?
- Did you even supply code for your question?
- Does your sample code compile/run?
- Is your sample code formatted to be readable?
- Did you include the full error message, if you get any?
- Is your spellchecker turned on?

Yes, this does not include a lot of useful/good information of the original list, but all that information is no use if it's not read, and I'd rather have them read the limited version than not read anything at all.

Comment: Getting that balance is definitely the problem. Maybe a "short form" and then a "long form" would be useful. (That's why I've given footnotes rather than including long items.)

Comment: Maybe when "bad question" with many negate votes, get a messages with a link to that page, the asker take some time to read all.

Comment: @Aristos: maybe I'm too cynical, but I'm afraid that no: the majority will simply never read that much test, they "just want their problem solved now!".

Comment: @Joachim sure, but those are easy to downvote and closevote. This list will help those OP's who really *want to know*, and saves existing users the effort of explaining the same things over and over and over

Comment: @Aristos [It does that now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aqxSF.png).

Comment: "Did you pay attention to the suggestions offered when you wrote the title?"

Comment: I would also add: "Do you have an actual problem to solve? This is not the place to discuss, rant or dump your frustration."

I was guilty of this so many times.

Comment: One might get better results with "average askers of bad questions" by giving them a playlist of short succinct video-clips demonstrating A) WHAT to do, B) WHAT NOT to do C) HOW to do it D) WHAT it'll look when it's done AND __most importantly__ E) How it'll help THEM get an answer to their question FASTER.

Comment: "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink."  Not even if you condense several gallons of water into a single drop and attempt to shove it up his nose with accompanying flashing red lights.  Some people *just won't* read the instructions.  The answer is *not* to further abbreviate the instructions.  Write the instructions so they are inviting, concise, and complete (which @JonSkeet has already accomplished), and then *ignore* the few who still can't be bothered to read them.

Answer (score 33):

Both question and answer are quite old, yet in my opinion still accurate. I would recommend to do a combination of both ideas. I suggest to start with a real short overview as posted by Joachim Sauer. But I would change the order of it to a more logical one (in my opinion):

- Did you explain your EXACT problem?
- Did you include the full error message, if you get any?
- What have you tried?
- Did you search for similar questions?
- What language/IDE are you using?
- Does your sample code compile/run?
- Is your sample code formatted to be readable?
- Is your spellchecker turned on?

and then I would turn each of those points into a hyperlink which can be clicked to get a more detailed comment, what is recommended, why and who to process this point.

That way you have something like a check list **which I would display like the "How to ask" orange box** visible whenever you ask a new question and which links to a FaQ/help section if you need further details on one or more points mentioned above.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

**"If a picture is worth a thousand words, a video must be worth millions (of words)"**.
A long and dense FAQ/checklist seems like a logical candidate for a video especially for newbies.

### Current Situation:

Significantly, it took at least 30-40 minutes to find an OK Stack Overflow how-to video. It seems like Stack Overflow is a text-only site (for ex-[Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) users maybe?). Joel Spolsky claims in his talks that Stack Overflow is a break from Usenet email-style conversations. *Maybe it's time to add some video help especially for newbies.*

Entry-Barrier:

---

- It's an oft-repeated complaint newbies don't **RTFM**, **FAQ**, **Checklists**, etc.
- From the newbie perspective the primary urge is to 'Answer my question/solve my problem/do my homework already!!'.
- To get better quality questions and answers we need to help newbies re-focus on Stack Overflow readership rather than the question. The video would help the newbie get over the entry barrier (kind of like a human-operator option of an IVR system).

### Reducing Entry Barrier:

- **Cognitive Style**: The communication medium has to suit the newbies' learning style  - Video, Audio, Kineaesthetic ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)).
- **Reduce time** for a newbie to get at least 60-80% of the process right the **first** time? **Show** him/her how to do it with an *example video*.
- **Reduce effort** by meeting them half-way by doing the reading/demonstration.
- **Non-native users** are not too comfortable with reading English. Adding subtitled small video-clips can go really far in reducing the entry barrier.

### Solution:

**A playlist of multiple 5-10 minute clips is more useful than a single big video.**

A playlist of short succinct video-clips demonstrating:

- **WHAT to do**
- **WHAT NOT to do**
- **HOW to do it**
- **WHAT it'll look like when it's done** and ***most importantly***
- **How it'll help newbies get an answer to their question FASTER**

### Advantages:

- If a newbie learns the top 80% of proper usage from the videos, the site should see a lot of happy users - newbies as well as moderators. The rest can come from links to FAQ, experience, etc.
- Helps moderators give short clips to reduce/avoid specific misbehavior.
- Helps "goal-oriented"/"attention-deficit"/"reading-disabled"/clueless newbies latch on fast.
- Helps reduce learning curve and bridge the learning-gap with **least effort**.

YouTube is full of newbie learning videos (from [Arduino](http://Arduino) to [graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) to cooking). Searching video-first and text-next saves time/effort and gives a starting point if it's worth following up.

### Resources:

These are currently available videos which can act as starting points.
They are too lengthy to be useful as they are. However, making 5-10 minute clips would make a huge difference in accessibility.

- [Video - Learning from Stack Overflow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ)
- [Video - Good Stack Overflow Citizen by Jeff Attwood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRRWDf-xB2Y)

### NOTE:

- The video-clips can be *incrementally* user contributed and *remixed* via [Mozilla Popcorn](https://popcorn.webmaker.org).
- TED.com and Mozilla use Amara.org team/individual subtitle editor to *crowd-source* subtitles and internationalize their videos.

Comment: Those videos are both longer than 50 minutes. Compare that with the "looong" checklist in this question - how long do you *really* think that takes to read? 2 minutes? 5? Surely not more than 10. I'm not saying that videos are a bad idea, but you don't seem to be consistent in the length of time you consider people are willing to put in.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Actually I suggest a Playlist of 5-10 minute videos instead of these long videos. Actually I'm working on a project to make large videos more accessible using social-media and clips, so I have spent quite some time thinking on this issue. The same problem is shared by __any online community__.

Comment: Also the videos themselves need not be static but can be incrementally created and remixed by users with Popcorn online video. This requires no additional infrastructure other than storing the video on youtube/vimeo etc.

Comment: It's not just about reading-time, but reading-ease. I've seen lots of people who avoid reading and would rather spend time dabbling or asking others verbally/visually through a diagram. Text-based online forums totally tilt the balance in favour of reading/writing people vs. auditory/visual cognitive style.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ironically I came to this question and your posts on SO __after__ hearing about you in the "Good StackOverflow Citizen" Video by Jeff Attwood! :-)

Comment: I don't think one can expect people who have trouble understanding the checklist to understand a 10 minute video. The way I perceive it, those asking low quality first questions want answers *right now!* - why bother watching a video? Why pay attention there? Why assume, that if you have trouble understanding the English in the checklist you can follow the spoken English of a video? The website I can try to translate with a dictionary.

Comment: @Schorsch Why assume that the newbie knows what he/she's doing wrong? Why assume they're not intelligent because they don't read a long rule-list? Why not give him/her a chance to edit their questions based on a 10 minute video howto. Adding the video brings back the human-touch and helps make re-framing the question into a learning experience. Adding simple subtitles for 10 minute video isn't be too hard by correcting auto-subtitles from youtube.

Comment: What I understand from Joel video talks is that SO wants techie layer to use questions as a sand-grain for pearl-making. This results in brusqueness towards newbies (intentional or otherwise). Instead it might be better to help newbies make better sand-grains then.

Comment: Understanding a checklist is not the same as recalling the checklist.
Seems like an old problem with 'Thou Shalt Not'!! I deleted the answer after downvotes. Undeleting it to give a different perspective on the issue.

Comment: It might be the case that [learning styles are a myth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhgwIhB58PA).

Comment: Our own [Kate](https://corecursive.com/056-memento-mori-with-kate-gregory/) [Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/) ([own, but separate](https://www.youtube.com/user/gregcons/videos) YouTube channel) has a Pluralsight course, *"[StackOverflow and StackExchange Site](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites)"*, in many parts, 5-10 minutes each. It was once on YouTube (e.g. *[StackOverflow and StackExchange Site Lesson 23](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuRlLjd3700)*), but the entire "Pluralsight" YouTube channel was deleted.

Comment: Native or not, yes, there is something to be said for audio and video in contrast to text: *"[People rarely read 90-minutes blog posts.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ7imwsX8ic&t=1h6m10s)"*

Answer (score 0):

I have here an ***invisible*** checklist that an asker can easily **paste** into their question and use as a checklist checking of items as they go. Just ***make sure*** to copy it **all**<sup>1</sup> and check to make sure it **doesn't show up** in the actual question.

```
<!--
[☐☑☒]
───────────────────────
 ☐ research before asking.
  ☐ web searches
  ☐ documentation
  ☐ stack overflow
───────────────────────
☐ what already tried
───────────────────────
☐ language
☐ platform version number
───────────────────────
☐ short code
☐ complete program 
───────────────────────
☐ correctly formatted code 
───────────────────────
☐ compiler error(if one)
───────────────────────
☐ Should Question has no code?(if doesn't contain code)
───────────────────────
☐ included the exception(if one)
  ☐ message
  ☐ stack trace
───────────────────────
☐ expected
☐ why expected it
☐ actual results
───────────────────────
☐ relevant information about system
───────────────────────
☐ question looks reasonable in formatting
───────────────────────
☐ spelling
☐ grammar
───────────────────────
☐ read to yourself
☐ enough information 
───────────────────────
-->
```

---

<sup>1</sup>*<sub>the `<!--` and `-->` are vital in order for the checklist to NOT show up. You DO NOT want the checklist to show up as it(most likely) has NO relevance to the question you may want to ask.</sub>*
Note: *<sub>This checklist is based off of the above checklist.</sub>*

Comment: This checklist is optimized for "sand", for debugging questions (version number, compiler error, exception, stack trace, expected vs actual, system information). It doesn't really matter if any of this is included. Just let people debug their own code.

Comment: @Alex This checklist is simply based off of the given checklist above and such things as (exception, compiler error, etc.). If the checklist does not adequately convey the checklist above then feel free to mention how it can be improved(without getting overly long).

Comment: I honestly don't think this serves any purpose other than to clutter up the question text, even "hidden."  There's just a ton of text with nothing to gain from it.

Comment: @Ajean I see how it would end up cluttering questions up however I thought it might be nice to have an actual checklist available, at least for people who are new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: *[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)*, not *stack overflow*.