# How can i report a user for downvote me?

Tags: discussion

A user downvote me because he don't understand my question, how can i report that to the administrators of stackoverflow? The reputation points are essential to vote in another questions and i don't have enough to that.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I already try help center, google, search questions ....

Comment: Looking at your question, I can understand the downvotes.  You failed to fully utilize available documentation.  You should not use Stack Overflow to do research you yourself should do.

Comment: And note that your question received 2 downvotes.  That's not the action of a single user.

Comment: @Hot Licks See you are like him, go see the question again, i ask HOW and not what types of encoding. He like you don't understand the question.

Comment: That was for the signature, i don't realize that i couldn't do that.

Comment: The available documentation would tell you how.

Answer (score 11):

The hover over text of the downvote button is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Someone found that your question is unclear or not useful. It is often also used if the question show little to no research effort, as these questions have little value to StackOverflow and usually take more effort to answer than to ask. If the majority of people that vote on your question vote that way, then that is a good indication you should probably change something in your question, or in how you ask a question.

It is not a moderator's duty to police how people vote. People are free to vote any way they want. Instead of demanding that a vote is reversed, read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center and ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) on meta, then fix any problem your question might have.

Comment: Except when a user verbally (with comments) gets upset because he cannot help me, and I point him to the answer to my own question... very nicely, I might add - and then he trolls my username and starts downvoting my last 5 answers, even commenting non-sensical reasonings as to why (yeah, same username!).  But before I can flag the comment, he deletes the comment - leaving the 5 downvotes in place.  There should be a way to report abusive users.

Comment: If the same user downvotes 5 questions in a day, they will get reverted by the automated task for reversal of serial voting. In fact, considering I don't see any negative reputation on your profile, that seems to be exactly what happened.

Comment: One downvote remained (you can see it in my Superuser profile), and it was the one he actually commented on. I started to flag the comment as trolling, and then he deleted his comment.  This all happened within like 5 minutes. https://superuser.com/questions/975950/custom-windows-installation-and-recovery-partition-with-sysprep/1200599#1200599

Comment: Comments are volatile, and it is also possible the comment was removed automatically because of several flags. The vote on that answer seems normal to me. It is not a particularly good answer. There is very little information in the answer itself, but just enough to not mark it for automatic deletion. The link is to a forum and not to official documentation it seems and the information might disappear in the future, leaving only the name of the tool as possible clue where to search for more information. I would have downvoted it too.

Comment: I am all for justified downvotes. :) (But don't downvote me! I'll make it more relavent).

Answer (score 9):

You could [flag your own question for moderator attention.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

However, it's extremely unlikely that a mod would reverse a single downvote. I'm not confident that mods even have that power. People are entitled to their own thoughts and opinions. The fact that you "need" the rep is irrelevant.

Comment: And how i do to that user never see my questions again?

Comment: @RuiOliveira there isn't a block feature

Comment: @RuiOliveira - If you're going to hang around Stack Overflow you'd better develop a thicker skin pretty fast.

Comment: Moderators cannot reverse votes, flagging wouldn't really help.

Comment: Moderators cannot even see *who* downvoted.