# Is Stack Overflow only for professionals?

Tags: discussion

I am an IT student. I found out about Stack Overflow one year ago and since then I've learned lots of things from here. Most of time I visit Stack Overflow when searching for a solution to my problem and I almost always find it on this site. But sometimes I need a more appropriate answer for a specific problem, so I ask questions.

I've asked only two questions and both of them were considered bad questions, so now my account is blocked for a while.

I'm not a pro or a genius who can raise a great topic, I'm just a passionate student. If you're a professor, instructor or teacher you'll find that your students have a ton of silly questions, just like me. Sometimes I do have a quite good question, but someone already asked it and I just followed it.

All that I want to say is that I ask to learn from it, so don't treat me and my questions so strictly, and if the answer is that this site is only for pros, not for amateurs like me, I'd better keep silence and just listen.

Comment: Students can ask good questions.

Comment: *"I'm not a pro or a genius who can raise a great topic"* - you don't *need* to be a pro or a genius to write a good question (although it would probably help!) Read the material in the Help Center on asking a good question, and things like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/3001761

Comment: I see only one question on your account, which is well received?

Comment: ^^^^^ 'This question came from our site for professional and enthusiast programmers.'

Comment: Students can surely be enthusiast programmers, but they can also be bone-idle deadbeats who just want their assignments done for them.  It is indeed quite difficult to place a question in the appropriate class, so take all the help and advice available and apply it well before asking your question.  If you get shoved in the wrong class, your rep will suffer:(

Comment: BANNED after only two questions?

Comment: Can an actual moderator give further comment on this?

Comment: I don't know if you can assume that research effort implies that the question came from a professional.  Because a lot of this site is heavily based on peer review and peer review may draw criticism if a well-researched question draws attention to an unpopular idea, and I think that rather than dispelling an unpopular idea with truth, the tendency for SE has and always will be: "Don't care. Flag for deletion and vote to close."

Answer (score 67):

> All I want to say is that I ask to learn from it, so don't treat me and my questions so strict...

Questions from students are perfectly welcome here, but they *will* be treated just as strictly as other questions. If we make exceptions for students, then the quality of posts on Stack Overflow would suffer badly. The reason you're able to learn so much from SO is *because* of these strict standards.

When you have a problem that you can't find an answer to, feel free to ask it on Stack Overflow. Just be sure to be clear about what you're trying to do, what you've tried so far, and what isn't working. Include any code, output, and error messages that you're getting. Remember that we aren't sitting with you like a co-worker or professor, so you need to post all of this information up-front so we can help you.

Comment: This answer is hilarious anno 2017.

Comment: The point of this heavily downvoted question was that he did that and STILL promptly received a question ban.  Thye notion that the community refuses to acknowledge that this does, in fact, happen detracts from the purpose of the entire umbrella of SE sites.  I get that users are not allowed to ask duplicate questions, but SE displays potential duplicates every time somebody asks a question and then people have the nerve to suggest that just because the person asking the question couldn't find the answer they needed that a BAN is the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 7):

I think that all of us are students, when we go to learn a new technology we are students, when a new language born all of us are students, the problem is put a little effort making good questions. In this networks of sites this is the point. If you don't put all your effort in your questions, we don't have all the information for help you, and remember that we can help you, but we need all the details and you must respect the rules.