# Is there a flag type priority when flagging a question?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

Suppose a question is clearly off topic, but it either violates several requirements at once, or the violation type can be flagged in several ways.
E.g.: 
The question is both **too broad** and **subjective** at the same time.
Or The question is both **subjective**, **asks for a resource** and **not related to programming**

- Do I have just pick one criteria at random? It doesn't really matter, at all?
- There is an implicit ordering of "flag types" which I should try to adhere to when flagging a question?

If there isn't a formal rule, are there practical considerations on this issue?

Comment: When a question can be closed for several reasons, I usually choose the one that "offended^" me the most - although I agree it doesn't really matter in the end because all the different reasons given by the voters will be displayed eventually. *(^Not really offended, but you see what I mean.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important thing to decide is if the question needs to be closed. So if you have no possible way to edit the question into shape so it becomes valuable for future visitors or answerable for one of our members you start wondering about closing for a particular reason.  I assume at this point that a very low quality flag is not an option.

Remember that each close reason comes with a specific post notice that contains one or more links to guidance in the help center.

I try to choose a reason that ends-up with a close notice that is most beneficial for the OP and should be the first thing to fix in the post. If there is really too much going wrong I down vote the post as well.

Beyond that you can leave a comment to point out what else needs fixing, where I try to link to relevant meta posts or FAQ's, for example the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

In the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room you can ask for advice on the best reason to pick when in doubt.