# Helping internet strangers who don't know what their problem is, exactly

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

**"why isn't this code working?"**

So, this comes up pretty regularly: Someone is experiencing incorrect/undesired behavior resulting from their code/configuration, but either they or the technology is new and so it could be any of a dozen or more different issues. Producing an MCVE is pretty difficult because the issue doesn't seem to show up in trivial examples. Perhaps the issue is the result of the interplay between several things, some of which may be unknown to the OP.

(To those that might be tempted to think ***all*** such questions are the result of inexperienced users posting bad questions, I offer this [counter-example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18036863/211627).)

**Usually "Off-Topic"**

It is possible to ask a question like this and keep it within the bounds of topicality, but it's very difficult. You must produce a wealth of information demonstrating what you've tried so far and hope that you've not left out any relevant piece of information (you probably have).

In practice, such a question would generally fall short of our standards and be closed as off-topic, and for very, very good reasons. Combing through message boards is annoying and frustrating to other users months or years later. The bulk of a back-and-forth conversation ("have you tried x? what's the value of y?") are of little value to others. We (hopefully politely) tell the authors of such posts to go somewhere else for that sort of help... their question/need is not "wrong", it just [doesn't fit on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180715/191410).

**Documentation was "Off-Topic", too**

Documentation was off-topic because it was too broad, but I think that the SE team correctly perceived that there was an unmet need out there for all those folks struggling with poorly-documented frameworks and APIs. Even though that effort didn't succeed as hoped (for now), it was worth a try and I think a lot of valuable lessons were learned in the process.

**The Current State of Affairs**

So, back to the first paragraph...

Questions that need a lot of back-and-forth refinement are usually handled by posting lots and lots of comments, all while hoping that no mods/crusty users (I'd be the second) come along and try to close your question.

Another would be the [infamous "**UPDATE:/EDIT:**" approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202472/191410), where users post answers suggesting a course of action, prompting the OP to update the question with additional information that may invalidate or obsolete current answers ("UPDATE: Tried xyz's suggestion and the foo still doesn't bar.").

Some users have [recommended chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/191410) as well, which might be ok, but: a) there's a rep threshold (barring entry to the vast majority of SO's visitors) and b) it produces no public artifacts (and is therefore generally useless to the vast majority of visitors).

**The Need is Real**

I think it's pretty obvious that there is a huge unmet need, but our response so far has largely been to send these folks away, or at least to turn down their requests for this-or-that-tweak that will make the site more message board-ish (which is as far as most people's imagination will take them). Maybe that is just the way things need to be and there's really no good solution to that problem that SO can help with, but it doesn't hurt to dream a bit, right?

**What would success look like?**

So if we were to introduce a new feature to handle this kind of "define-the-problem-as-I-go" question, what would the goals be?

- It'd need a definite beginning (ask a question), middle (back-and-forth), **and end** (problem/solution found, evolution to something different).
- Very low "noise" for non-involved users during the "back-and-forth" phase.
- A low barrier to entry for users that would like to jump in during the "back-and-forth" phase. I shouldn't have to read *every* response to get the gist of where the conversation is at.
- **Critical:** the production of a concise, useful artifact when the problem/solution is discovered.

  The production of artifacts is critical, otherwise all this effort produces nothing valuable for anyone else and folks just burn out. Artifacts also produce rewards and pay dividends, as future users vote on helpful content, giving authors rewards and incentives to continue. And, of course, producing such an artifact is *the hard part*™.

**In Summary**

I'm not exactly sure what this new feature(s) could or would look like, but the need is clearly there and I think there's a lot of potential benefit for everyone, if only we could figure out how to cull the useful information from a back-and-forth conversation once the issue/solution has been properly identified (and remove/hide the cruft).

Maybe it's "just one of those things" that's simply too complex, or maybe folks think that our current system works *good enough*™ (I think many users would disagree), but the SE team/community is creative and smart and I think improvements to this aspect of question-asking are worth some serious consideration and discussion.

Comment: I believe the [mentor project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project) is trying to solve at least part of this issue.

Comment: 'why isn't this code working?' When it comes to anything beyond the most simple examples, I do not believe that it is possible to engage with the large number of SO posters in a more directly interactive manner in any effective way.  Extracting info from OP's is like pulling teeth, and system level testing/debugging is essentially not possible by exchanging text:(

Comment: The bigger question is to what degree SO users with families, mortgages and expensive college loans to pay off are willing to support Jeff Bezos' sweat shops.  There is a limit to that, lately I've been seeing it crossed daily.

Comment: @HansPassant "Jeff Bezos' sweat shops"?

Comment: Jeff Bezos has a company that needs a lot of software written.  In 2015 he became the biggest investor in SO with a forty million dollar investment, doubling the total of previous investments.  There is an implicit quid pro quo behind such large chunks of money that nobody knows anything about.  Marc Andreessen is another one, he got in cheap.

Comment: _"In 2015 he became the biggest investor in SO with a forty million dollar investment, doubling the total of previous investments"_ Ah, interesting tidbit. This seems like a bit of a conspiracy theory, but...*shrugs*.

Answer (score 13):

> The Need is Real

Yes, there is a need.

Stack Overflow however is not the place to meet that need. Forums can handle this, for those people who want to delve into remote debugging.

The reason why SO shouldn't provide it is:

> the production of a concise, useful artifact when the problem/solution is discovered.

See, that's just not really possible. For these kinds of questions, the solution is usually either something small somewhere or something incredibly detailed. In the first case, there is no effective way to connect the question/discussion/whatever to the answer, since the one only accidentally led to the other. If you're asking an OpenGL question and forgot to initialize a variable somewhere, that's no different than any other uninitialized variable issue.

In the second case, it's difficult to distill a complex collision of issues into anything remotely searchable. Such a problem could be at the intersection of threading, file access, and various other things, which makes it very difficult for the next person who happens to have that problem find a solution.

And in both cases, it requires *effort* to generate that artifact. Effort beyond merely helping that person.

SO works because there is no distance between "helping the person" and "generating a useful artifact"; doing the one instantly causes the other.

There's no way that a discussion will automatically create a "useful artifact". Oh yes, it can be distilled into one. Or if you want to sift through it, you can gather useful knowledge from one. But it won't happen without effort.

Comment: I largely agree with you, but I'd like to make two subtle distinctions: 1) I think the "Current State of Affairs" section indicates that the existing tooling could use some refinement, but I'm not really sure what that would look like. 2) I didn't say that it needs to be on Stack Overflow, exactly (though it could end up there). Before our documentation beta I would have probably given the same answer you gave, but I think we've set a precedent for trying out new sub-sections of the site, and I wonder if it might be worth considering one for this kind of need.

Comment: Tooling for this would not be a "refinement", it'd be an entirely different software platform. Not quite a forum, which doesn't support the definite beginning/middle/end, but certainly not a QA either.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, no matter how much work is done with a user's question, there is just no way that it fits at Stack Overflow. It may be server related, or it may be environment configuration related, or it may just be that asking Stack Overflow to name that thing just isn't tenable. As for the examples which have code, and can at least have an answer (this is where many code based questions fail, as they do not have verifiable answers), they do get them.

The hardest part about a large portion of questions (not users - sometimes they just haven't acclimated, this should be addressed purely from a questions point of view) posed is explaining they don't fit here. This may seem counter productive, because many users look at questions and say "I could answer that", but since it isn't a good fit here instead they remove the post. This is by design though, otherwise we would just be reddit. No one wants that.

We all do our best to deal with the middle ground, and sometimes it works out, and sometimes it doesn't. Overall though, I think there is a proven history of it working very well.

---

> RE: "I guess I'm asking that if we were willing to try out a documentation site for content that wouldn't git the Q/A format, is it worth considering something similar for another class of questions?" (from a comment on this answer)

I think that is kind of what the mentorship program is all about, as was noted in a comment on your post. I am currently in the mentorship program, so perhaps briefly giving you an example of the workflow can illustrate that this type of guidance is at least being considered.

Workflow:

- User visits Ask Question page
- Qualifying user opts for help from mentorship
- There is a chat room which contains a one-boxed example of the draft question posted automatically after the user opts in
- A mentor adopts the mentee and enters another chat room with only the mentor and mentee
- The draft question is visible to the mentor, and the two users can then converse in chat to improve the question - no matter how vague or off topic it may be.

Sometimes this results in a question being improved, sometimes it is simply "this is not going to work here". Often the questions start out very vague, and occasionally they result in actually refined answerable questions. I am not saying it is perfect, but it is giving users a chance if they are not accustomed to the site setup and have a "why isn't this working" issue. Some users to genuinely improve from the process though.

Comment: Totally agree that these kinds of questions wouldn't work on SO, nor would I want them there. I guess I'm asking that if we were willing to try out a documentation site for content that wouldn't git the Q/A format, is it worth considering something similar for another class of questions? The trick would obviously be to generate some useful content when you're "done"... not really sure if that's possible. But I think it's worth a think.

Comment: @JDB - Please see my response in the RE: section of my edit above.