# I have asked two questions, and both of them were downvoted

Tags: support, questions

I have asked the following two questions on Stack Overflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980437/is-there-any-way-to-hack-python-script-cgi-file-from-web-server
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006260/please-help-me-to-find-bug-in-below-code

I don't know where I am going wrong and why people are downvoting my questions.

Comment: You posted an *image* of code, and you didn't even bother to embed the image directly into the question. I would downvote this 100 times if I could. Come on, do you really have to ask what is wrong with the question?

Comment: Mainly because both of them are low quality. Have a read of [ask] and [help] to help you better your questions and then edit where applicable. (cc @CodyGray I was trying to be nice but you sniped me)

Comment: Remember: when posting something in meta, you accelerate the effect of the community on your post, whenever it is positive or negative. This is called the "meta effect".

Comment: Beyond the advice and links already given you also might want to take the advice in the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) into consideration.

Comment: OK, I looked at these questions and, sure enough, they were VLQ and I downvoted them, no problem there.  I have noticed, however, that an large number of VLQ questions have unwanted links to externals like imgur.  When signing up for new accounts, is it specifically mentioned that such links are unacceptable?  I just tooke the tour and quickly looked through the help - it was NOT obvious that the ephemeral exernal links would get down/close votes.

Comment: As for inserting picture *links*: maybe Shyam did not yet have 10 rep at that moment?

Answer (score 29):

Your first question has no clear purpose. You've tagged it with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) but don't seem to actually have tried anything with these technologies to get the result you want.

It's been closed as "too broad", because I assume that even if someone managed to provide you with an answer, it would go over your head. You've shown no attempt to solve it yourself, and you don't even describe what you mean by "hack".

---

Your second question is badly titled, you don't appear to have made any effort yourself, and you don't provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of what it is you actually want. "It doesn't work" and "Please find the bug" aren't good questions that will help any other user.

---

Both your questions had received comments with feedback prior to your post here, you don't seem to have properly taken that on board though.