# Stack Overflow and software consulting

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a tendency for certain questions on SO to sound more like engineering projects than programmatic clarification. You all know the questions I'm talking about, where the implied correct answer requires more lines of code than the page the question is posted on.

Anyway the real question here is if there is a line for questions on Stack Overflow. Obviously questions should be specific and through, sure to explain what has been tried and what limitations exist. That said are there any guidelines for what a reasonable magnitude of question to ask is?

I.e. is there anything anywhere that says Stack Overflow is for answers, not solutions?

Comment: you mean anything beyond [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [the checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)?

Comment: Sure, the ability to vote to close as too broad.

Comment: the guidelines is normally to look into the help center before asking a question. Had you done that, you would've seen EXACTLY what you're asking...

Comment: Requirement and/or functional specifications get down/close voted quite quickly, usually.  I DCV them immediate.