# How should I improve a question with downvotes but minimal feedback

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

I have recently received a message that some of my questions have not been well-received, so am trying to improve some with negative votes, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans. However, I don't see what is wrong with this one: [Pointer to existing 2d array of unknown size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034783/pointer-to-existing-2d-array-of-unknown-size), and though I requested clarification about the downvotes, none was provided.

What would be the best approach to improving a question such as this, when it is not clear why it was badly received?

Comment: You seem to have gotten quite a bit of feedback on that question, in the form of comments and answers.

Comment: To be more specific, I am referring to feedback regarding question quality.

Comment: Votes are also used to convey usefulness. Do you think your question is useful to anyone else? Of your questions, I'd suggest it's more likely to be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551320/language-to-use-with-ip-address that's brought up the warning for you. Focus there.

Comment: Thanks, I have flagged that one to be moved to super user, as it's probably more appropriate there.

Comment: @Dimpl I don't think that question you flagged will fly on Super User. maybe English Language and Usage will take it.

Comment: Not that it will ever fly but I've seen (and asked) multiple legitimately phrased, well-researched questions that were contextual appropriate to the SO site at the time that were downvoted without explanation. If you're going to downvote, you should be required to explain why - especially if it negatively impacts a user's rep.  A simple, short comment would suffice (e.g. "Your question sucks. How do you live with yourself?").

Comment: @sparecycle: Requiring downvote explanations has been thoroughly rejected by the SE userbase and developers many dozens of times in the past. That's a total non-starter. Your suggested comment gives an excellent example of why this is not a good idea, since it's entirely non-constructive feedback: rather than giving any idea of how to improve anything at all, it's just a rudely-phrased instruction to give up in despair. Simply requiring explanations without some way to make inadequate explanations tend to prevent downvoting won't do anything to prevent bad votes or help fix questions either.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Cool, all I'm saying is that if I downvote a question, I'm going to constructively tell you why. I upvoted your comment by the way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You picked up these down votes on the first day, based on the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36034783/timeline) and by the fact that your question entered the [Triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11651788), I even suspect those down votes were casted right after posting.

That is indicated by the first comment on your question and the comment vote it got. Passers-by agreed with the commenter and accompanied that agreement with a down vote.

Lesson to be learned: post code that either compiles as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least satisfies commonly accepted syntax rules.

In later comments I see you post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034783/pointer-to-existing-2d-array-of-unknown-size#comment59719562_36034783):

> A 2d array is not a pointer to a pointer... except that it kind of is. See stackoverflow.com/questions/26454022/…. I asked this question as that answer doesn't address the situation where all values for the 2d array are assigned in one statement.

Lesson to be learned: include relevant research in your question when posted, not as comments when you get some push back.

I don't fully understand the delicacies of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034783/pointer-to-existing-2d-array-of-unknown-size#comment59719176_36034783), but the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034783/pointer-to-existing-2d-array-of-unknown-size#comment59719229_36034783) reads like that user gave up on you. If you want to prevent that, make sure your question contains enough context so that such comment exchange doesn't need to happen. But I might be interpreting that wrong as a non-native English speaker.

If there is a lesson to be learned: keep it constructive, but that goes for all commenters.

Overall I see some room for improvement. You might want to go over the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) that covers more points.

Final note: asking for explanation of down votes in comments under your question often attract more down votes, as does advertising a question on Meta...