# Why are my questions going unanswered?

Tags: discussion

I am new to stackoverflow. I have now posted 3 questions in the last few days, and one I resolved myself, and the second I posted the answer to myself too, because no one did for over 24 hours and in that time I worked out how to do that particular issue myself. Now I have asked a third question, and I just feel I am getting ignored?

I have put as much detail in all of the questions I asked. So I really do not know why no one is choosing not to reply?

Comment: the code layout on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36908711/578411) needs fixing, and you need to read [mcve] because an image of your code is not appreciated. Just [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855324/trying-to-setup-twitter-oauth-and-getting-error) this one. Remember to not add meta-noise. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881839/sync-two-table-user-id-and-thanks-confirmation-to-user-with-twitter-oauth) seems too much code. Again see [mcve]. See also the [Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: this is what I meant to happen for  [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, i will delete the one you said, but when i tried adding the code for the process.php file, it wouldnt paste it properly, it kept breaking it up into weird sections and not all in one code insert snippet?

Comment: See the formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: thanks again, but that is such a hell of a lot of extra work though, and very time consuming :P :(

Comment: Yes, that is what we expect from questions, to be time consuming on your part. If you expect SO to be an easy *dump my question and see what happens* you'll have a terrible experience.

Comment: Well crafted and formatted questions WILL get more answers. Trying to plow through someones question where the formatting has gone bye bye is a mess and will mostly end up being not read. If you post some code, in some cases you'll put up a mock Project to have a look at the code and how it acts up, having the code as an image will result in even fewer people willing to "re-write" the code off of and image.

Comment: but also, saying that, i did now find a little similar post, and it basically said as an answer that twitter do not allow iframes to be posted in fancybox, but maybe since that has been posted and answered, maybe something has changed and that is possible?

Comment: Is it better for you to do all the work or all of the people who are trying to help you *for free*?

Comment: i see all your points and thanks :) i will edit the question and remove the image, and post just small snippets of the process file code then :)

Comment: Summary - if you can work out your problems yourself, (a very good thing that can only add to your own experience and skill), why are you wasting everyone else's time?

Comment: @Martin James, well the thing is, when i posted those questions i kind of fixed myself, i was stuck at that point, so that was why? so why is it wasting anyone elses time? i mean yes i asked a Question, but i didnt expect it to not get any replies. but hey, i am still learning php and mysql stuff, but it was good for me to actually figure my own problem out yes i agree with you on that point. :)

Comment: Remember that SO does not exist to help you, or to teach you things. On SO visitors find answers to their questions so we optimize for that goal: Have questions that are interesting for many users, not just for you.Trying to use SO as a regular forum will not end well.

Comment: Ok i understand that is how SO works :)

Comment: " I really do not know why no one is choosing not to reply?" They are either not interested in your questions or your questions are written so (too specific, not clear enough, missing information) that it would be too much work answering them. Solution: Improve your questions and hope for the best. However, there is always a chance you are unlucky and just noone comes by and answers your question. It's definitely nothing personal. Just bad luck then.

Comment: See also: [Attracting more traffic to Stack Exchange question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39939/attracting-more-traffic-to-stack-exchange-question) and links therein.

Comment: You posted... an image of your code?  You did that?  YOU ANIMAL. *checks the programming language* PHP?  You sicken me.

Comment: lol Will, liked your comment :)

Answer (score 5):

I have some thoughts about your most recent question.

This arrangement:

```
line 8-12

    if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['token']  !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {

    //If token is old, distroy session and redirect user to index.php
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');

line 14-20
```

is not necessary.  The line numbers are just a distraction, and they don't add any new information to the question.  I have edited your question accordingly.  See how much easier it is to read?

The community either has missed this, or didn't bother to read your entire post due to it's length, but at the end of the day, your question amounts to either "What's wrong with my code dump," or "How do I do ${this}?"

Code troubleshooting questions have specific requirements that you did not fulfill:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

"How do I do ${this}?"  I personally prefer that you'd asked that.  Unfortunately, you would have been asked "What have you tried" from the community, you would have pasted in your code, and we would be back to where we are now.

Comment: I answered a comment u left in my other question. I have asked **if this is possible** it is a question? is it not?

Comment: It's a proxy for "How do I do this?"  Anything is possible, given enough time, money and programmer effort.  Don't get too hung up on that; there are many more valuable points in my answer above.

Comment: Ok i understand your point :) and thanks for taking the time to comment and edit my post for me