# What should I do if I don't know if my question is bad?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

I recently had this situation where I was a bit frustrated with something and I just couldn't figure it out by searching on the webz... It wasn't an interesting question, but I asked anyway. I got several down votes and that felt kinda bad.

I care about contributing constructive questions, should I not post and try to figure it out by myself next time when I get the same problem?

Comment: The [help] has some guidance. Is it this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198832/array-unshift-in-an-immutable-way

Comment: Thank you for the help Alexander! I should have read up on the help center before I asked :)

Comment: While it's not necessarily a bad question, in that there's not much more you can really add to it, I think it may have been downvoted as it appears to show a lack of research, as the solution is found within the javascript documentation for concat. That being said, it does take a little bit of a jump to realise you can append items to the front by reversing the `concat` call arguments. If you really did *thorough* research and still came up short, there's nothing more you could have done here, as far as I can tell. Remember, votes are subjective - so always take them with a grain of salt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267569/webpack-resolve-alias-works-with-sass-but-not-when-importing-javascript is not a question.  You must actually ASK something.  Don't just state that you have a problem and expect people to guess what your question is.

Comment: @VladyVeselinov - Out of curiosity, what was hard about finding the help center? Should it have been more visible? After finding the help center, do you feel like your questions going forward will be improved as a result?

Comment: It's my fault, it's on the top bar, I don't see how it can be more visible than that. I recently started learning how to code and I was inclined to start coding without thinking, because I wanted a fast result.

Comment: Use the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) before you post and keep in mind that asking a question on  Stack Overflow is your last resort not your first.