# How to remove "on hold" mark after editing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

I asked [How to retrieve outliers from ceres solver result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379557/how-to-retrieve-outliers-from-ceres-solver-result). It was short but, in my opinion, it was clear. However, it was put on hold as unclear.

I've done some editing to clarify, added a comment and even flagged the question. Two days have passed but no one else has put a comment or reopened the question. So:

- If they don't know about my edit, how can I notify them?
- If they do know, why have they paid no attention?
- If it is normal that this operation takes so long, why didn't they just comment instead of putting the question on hold?

Comment: You wait. Editing gets your question more attention, and if people think it's sufficiently improved they will vote to reopen it, at which point it is put in the reopen queue for others to agree or disagree. You don't notify the people who voted to close; if they want to come back and review it, they will.

Comment: As to your third question: why would they? I frankly don't much care how long it takes someone to get their question reopened after I've closed it (except in the case where I've incorrectly dupe-hammered, as that is solely on me). Five users have agreed that their question was bad, and it's not like there isn't plenty of help on asking good ones if you can be bothered to read it.

Comment: Your edit did put it in the re-open queue where it didn't [get re-opened](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12450334). My guess is that reviewers want to see some attempt from you to get the outliers. I do admit that your question has improved so you're on the right track. Use the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to add your attempt.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my question and for explanations. @rene Is there some mehanism to notify me if my question reviewed after editing? It's hard to me to improve my question when there is no comment or even notifications that it reviewed but still not good enough.

Comment: You don't get notified but you can keep an eye on the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37379557/timeline) of your post to see what happened with it.

Comment: @rene it will be enought, thanks.