# How can users see past questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

When a new question is asked by the users, the older ones are neglected or unseen by anybody. Or the older questions will go down to the last, and the newer one at the top. Then more and more questions were accumulated on the top. So the people will not get their proper result. Stack Overflow had a lot more questions without any answers.

The example given below the snippet got two upvotes, but it will not get any result till now. And I can't finf my question at the front page (question section) after some minutes. By every refresh, newer questions are being added.

Is there a way to view/shuffle the older questions to the home page, so that everybody can see the older questions too and others get some good results?

Example for similar question.
....................................................................

[image: This is a similar question]

Comment: Yes.  Bounties can get more attention for unloved questions.  Also, edits "bump" posts back to active list.

Comment: But do not do a pointless edit to bump the question.  That is frowned upon.  The edit should make the question better.

Comment: You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have an example of a question that you believe is not getting enough attention? It is possible that the questions(s) you have in mind have some problems that make it less likely they will get answers.

Answer (score 6):

> When a new question is asked by the users, the older ones are neglected or unseen by anybody.

No, that is not completely true. Enough users have filters or feeds on specific tags so they get notified when a new question is posted.

> So the people will not get their proper result.

Remember that every user here on Stack Overflow is just volunteering their time. There is no guarantee your question will be answered nor is there an agreed timeline. Allow [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) for answers.

> I have a lot more questions without any answers.

That is probably caused by the fact that your questions are unclear, too broad, a duplicate, not well researched, poorly worded. All aspects you can and should work on. The [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) might be handy for that.

> Is there any way to view/shuffle the older questions to the home page, so that everybody can see the questions and others get some good results?

One of the options you have to add additional info you've found when you continued your own debugging, studying, experimenting and researching the issue at hand. Also a [good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) that matches with your post body and the correct tags will help in getting the right people to look at and/or find your question.

If you have a reputation of [75 of more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) you can offer a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to get your question featured but that still is not a guarantee for an answer.