# How to find the correct place to post a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I posted a question about Sass development and it didn't go so well with the community. You can see it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893581/is-sass-for-development-only. I've seen other [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass) questions on Stack Overflow and I'm not sure what I should have done differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what Stack Overflow is and specially what it isn't.

First things first, [Stack Overflow is **not** a forum.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum). It is also mentioned in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) where you'll find ...

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

To learn which questions you can get answers for you'll have to read the help page on [What is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That a tag exists doesn't automatically mean your question is on-topic. It is best to start at the tag-wiki of [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sass/info) but unfortunately that tag isn't  very clear which questions can be asked.

After that you should read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that explains what a question for Stack Overflow should look like as well as tips on which questions to avoid. On meta you'll find the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) which is a practical guide to make sure your question is on par.

Let's analyze your question:

> I'm new to Sass. I haven't been able to determine when exactly Sass is used in a dev > staging > production workflow. Is it only used in dev to generate the css file and then you move that css file to production? Or is Sass actually utilized on production?

Your question is bit too broad. Behind that question a seasoned Sass engineer sees a lot of problems looming that are not addressed and it would require them a lot of text to provide an answer that is useful for you and foremost the future visitors of that question.

I'm not a Sass SME but I assume there are tutorials out there on the internet that explain the different deployment and staging options you have.

Instead of that question you could have asked (I have no clue where sass is about):

> I have created my site.sass file and all works fine on my box. I used this code to foo the bar

> ```
>    @Foo+bar { image: url('@dev');}
> ```

> When I promote this to my staging environment the css doesn't work because the of the @dev reference. How can I configure the settings that are specific to each environment like dev, staging and production?

Answers to above question might tell you not to foo the bar, to use url-env(@dev) or that you need to run the sass compile for or on each environment.

That are useful answers that are practical and visitors can easy see if they face the same problem you described in your question.

If you're not sure if a question you want to ask is on-topic, even after doing all your research in the help center and by going over similar questions in the tags you plan to post on, you can ask here on meta for a [site-recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). You'll have to explain where your doubts are about the on-topicness. You can include (a summary of) your actual question so the members here can judge where it could go, be it on main or an other programming related site within the [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid).