# Even though I set bounties, I received no answers; what is wrong with my questions?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty, question-quality

I've been a member for over a month and it seems I do really need to improve my skills when it comes to asking questions. I've given bounties to 3 questions of mine so far:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942033/3ds-max-plugin-which-exports-steps-to-generate-the-scene (+50)
- [Recursive to iterative using a systematic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567618/recursive-to-iterative-using-a-systematic-method) (+50)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987494/how-to-design-a-nodegraph-widget-which-contains-subgraphs (+100)

and the results were really poor. I have not received any answers yet, and I have no clue why my questions weren't answered. Furthermore, the bounty period is almost over for two of them, which means a complete waste of reputation.

So, could anyone explain to me what's been wrong with these three questions and how to improve them? Is it a language barrier? How can I overcome that? Are the questions just really poor? What can I do differently? Or are they just too difficult to expect a good answer?

Comment: I just took a quick look, but "how do I get started", "how to design", and "please explain me that book chapter" questions are usually too broad to work well on SO. SO works best for specific problems.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. He's asking very specifically *what is wrong with these questions*, which is a perfectly reasonable Meta question. These aren't a lot of fun to answer, perhaps, but it's not a duplicate of "what are my options".

Comment: You're asking really broad questions. "How do I get started" is never specific enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The voting on questions like this is why I'm having a hard time defending Meta against those who say it is full of cranky assholes. This post is a shining example of someone asking the community for help about their questions - yet to someone unfamiliar with Meta's culture it looks like it's something *we don't want* (it is sitting at net -5 now)

Comment: @CodyGray I've edited and simplified this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567618/recursive-to-iterative-using-a-systematic-method) quite a lot, what do you think?

Comment: For the 3ds Max question, you could ask "Where is sample code located for an exporter, where is documentation located, and/or what classes in the API are related to file export".  That way you're asking for concrete, non-subjective information.  And if you tried something which is not working, then report the details, demonstrating your prior research and effort.  The desire for general guidance is understandable, however StackOverflow is not an ideal platform for tutoring.  BTW - were your 3ds Max concerns ever resolved?

Comment: @MichaelsonBritt Wow, this one is really old one, at that time I was a total newbie using exchange sites like Stackoverflow, nowadays I know more or less how to formulate better questions (not always) :) . Regarding your question, few months ago I'd played a bit more with maxscript and found some ways to do it, although that project got stuck and switched to creating my own 3d node-based editor instead. I also recall I'd given [bounties](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150622/3ds-max-plugin-exporting-steps) on gamedev and nobody never replied

Answer (score 17):

Taken from the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942033/3ds-max-plugin-which-exports-steps-to-generate-the-scene) you linked (emphasis mine):

> **I'd like to code one 3ds max plugin** which exported the neccesary steps to generate my scene. That means, the plugin won't export any raw data related to the geometry, only the steps in some file format my engine will be able to recreate.
>
> For instance, **some steps** i'd like to capture:
>
> [...]
>
> The purpose of this plugin would be providing a final file format whose size is the order of few bytes.
>
> **So, how to get started? What are the necessary functions from Max API or MaxScript which could help me out with this task?**
>
> One more note, ideally i'd be recording the final steps to create the scene, not the undo&redo actions... but only if that's even possible.
>
> **Any example from anyone who coded something similar will be really welcome.**
>
> Thanks in advance.

There are quite a few things that are - to put it simply - wrong with your question.

**First of all**, you do not name a clear problem. You don't give the people reading your question anything to begin working with, you're basically just saying what you want, not what you have, and not what you have tried thus far.

**Secondly**, step-by-step-guides are unusual on SO, and that's basically what you're requesting here.

**And, lastly**, you ask for examples from anyone who coded something similar (basically asking for a guide).

All in all I don't find it surprising that your questions didn't get any answers despite being bountied. Try to keep your questions simple and clear with a clear problem to begin with, and keep out noise (Thanks and so on). Also stick to the guidelines regarding questions, and [read this!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

---

Side note: Bounties are mainly something used to get more attention, it's not really a magical tool that'll make the experts go nuts trying to solve your problem/answer your question. Reputation is a nice bonus, but that's it, it's not a payment method :)