# Why do my questions keep getting put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I've asked two similar questions in the past day or so. (This was my main question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293503/how-to-move-large-file-directories-over-lan-in-c)

The first one I got a lot of downvotes on. So with the second one, I revised it and tried to be specific about what I am asking. But once again, it has been down voted, marked for deletion and put on hold for being too "broad".

What am I doing wrong, and how can I improve the questions I ask?

Comment: Use the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for starters your question is incoherent; it starts with:

> moves large (20GB+) file directories across a LAN [...] What is the recommended way to do this, without failing when hit with network interruptions?

But then at the end it's:

> all I need is a way of automating this robocopy script so I can enter in the details of the user, host and receiver, so it can be run on multiple new machines quickly.

So which question are you asking?

---

At any rate, the first "how do I copy files across the network efficiently" is fairly broad, but *could* be on-topic if asked correctly. Such a question would look something like:

> I am copying *n* small files (average filesize: *n* bytes) over the network with is code:
>
> ```
> Working example code which demonstrates the problem.
> ```
>
> This takes *n* seconds; so the average transfer speed is *n* bytes/second.
>
> I tested my network speed by copying a single large *n* file, and this took *n* seconds, which is much faster!
>
> How can I improve the transfer speed of this program?

As you can see, this is a very different question from the one you asked.

---

Your second question − "all I need is a way of automating this robocopy script" − is not a question, but a code assignment. What did you try? Where did you get stuck? A good start to solve this is https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C%23+run+external+programs

Comment: Great help! Your right, the second part wasn't a question, when I was getting the down votes, I tried to add more detail.