# My question seems to be too broad; should I post a new one or try to update?

Tags: discussion, answers

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339404/laravel-passport-vue-components-showing-as-fragments) question and I realise now that this is not a very good example to get help.

I am trying to understand how to handle improving my question, or whether I should just post a new one.

Initially, I thought that my problem was with my the components from Passport not working; however, now I come to realise that it's actually ANY Vue component in my project.The problem is far more deeply rooted than I thought. This makes it very hard to make a reproducible example that is minimal.

I guess my problem is that I need to find out why a component would fragment, so that I can gain some clarification on how to fix it. Should I post this into a new question?

I feel that if someone looks at that post it's unanswerable, but if I try and widen the scope of the question, it doesn't really make sense to the original post. Should it be closed?

Comment: Users generally hate to visit a link to make a mental picture of your problem. Your post has three links. Try to come up with an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that an expert can copy-paste into their own environment and test it. Maybe the [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) can help as well.

Comment: Thankyou allot, i will bare that in mind. Very useful to know

Comment: So is your opinion i should close this question?

Comment: Do you mean *this* question of the question on main? Either way the answer is no. This one here on meta needs an answer if I don't find a dupe, your question on main needs to be edited by you so it becomes answerable.

Comment: Always fix your bad stuff.  Stripping down your code to the bare essentials needed to repro is always preferred.  Code dumps often attract downvotes.  If you can edit your question to remove unnecessary markup, I'd suggest you try.  Your other code snippets were sized perfectly.  I've edited them all into the question.

Comment: You can always ask about _how to proceed_ with debugging/analyzing, although you must still be specific and focused. You need to figure out [exactly which one or two pieces you are missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/159251) and ask for help finding or fitting those.

Comment: I think that's probably what I need to do. The thing is, I realise now that i need to find out WHY an element could fragment rather than why it has in this project. I feel it will help aid my learning as well. I am starting to see the light :>