# Downvotes and comments deletion for no apparent reason

Tags: discussion

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436716/the-segment-is-already-unlocked-error-158-while-trying-to-load-dll)

and got an initial response as if I'm trying to write malware and downvote. After politely explaining what I am trying to achieve, the respondent understood and asked me to share MVCE. So far, so good. But then, I found all the discussion deleted without any reason. Latter, got 2 more downvotes for requesting people who are downvoting to provide a reason.

This looked more like a rage downvoting to me than anything. I finally deleted my question because of no. of downvotes because nobody will anyway look at that anymore after seeing the downvotes.

Can someone tell me what my mistake is and why the comments got deleted?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Checked the link above and my question doesn't fit there anywhere. I did google, researched and genuinely felt that the error code doesn't have enough detail/documentation anywhere.

Comment: The essence is you can't tell. Downvotes are given like candy at carnival.

Comment: The question was downvoted because "I wrote some code and I get error 158" did not look like a promising start for Q+A that is going to be useful to other programmers.  We are using votes to ensure that questions that should be answered get the views they need.  This one doesn't need any.  Please review the help center to find out how to ask a question, should give you enough cues to re-ask the question properly.

Comment: You might want to apply the [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as well.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone tell me what my mistake is and why the comments got deleted?

Moderators can, and will, delete conversations that are no longer relevant/constructive.

In this case, IMO, they did you a *favour* by removing the comments after the issue was resolved - otherwise, some people might have just read the first couple comments, assumed it was about malware, and downvoted.  (People don't read.)

The downvotes are a separate issue, they have nothing to do with the moderator action. Perhaps they were cast during the time it looked like you were trying to write malware? We'll never know for sure.

It may be worth asking again. Do take David's advice into account, though:

> You are writing a credential provider? That's fair enough. There was me thinking your code was injected into that process. Show us a MCVE for your credential provider then

Comment: "(People don't read.)" Or rather, they read what they want to hear and ignore what they don't want to. If they didn't read, they wouldn't have seen the first couple comments about malware ;)

Comment: I guess its time for me to move on. However, it would be nice of users to "give a reason/suggest edit on question/hint on" rather than clicking downvote and let million other users ignore it as well just because there is no time to read !

Comment: It indeed would be nice - but there's no way to tell. (A popular feature request is to force people to justify their vote, but that's an awful idea that wouldn't work for several practical reasons.)

Comment: @SaileshD: Downvotes are *not for you*. They're for other people. They're a sign to people looking to answer interesting questions that says, "This question is not good; go look at something else." While you seem wiling to improve your question, the fact is that your question as it currently stands is a low-quality question and therefore deserves to have that sign on it.