# I unknowingly broke Stack Overflow etiquette and my question was downvoted because of it, how can I now get my question answered?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-questions

I asked a question on Stack Overflow. Due to my inexperience in the topic I didn't quite know how to ask the question to fully get across what I needed to know. I think partially because of this the question received no answers.

After some more research into the topic I found exactly what I needed to ask and how to put it into a question. Because of this I *thought* it was a good idea to delete my old question, re-make another question with the new phrasing etc so that it would be better understood and have a better chance to be answered. I *thought* the question would be different and this would be okay.

I understand now that this was a mistake. My question was downvoted and immediately got a comment telling me "Man, don't delete your question and repost. People don't like that here."

I completely understand what I did wrong and how I should have gone about it, needless to say I wouldn't do it again. But what this leaves me with now is, a deleted question, a perfectly good question downvoted because of the fashion it was posted. And no answer.

I would still like an answer to the question, what would be the best course of action to take to best get one from this point?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you assume that you got "punished" for breaking etiquette.  Not the first conclusion to draw, it is still a very vague "it doesn't work" bug report without any hint whatsoever how anybody else could reproduce the problem.  The odds you'll get an answer with the question in its current state are rather low.

Comment: Your question is just crying out for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You might also want to use the [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: On top of what others toldld you, you may need patience as well. Remember people answering donate their time to you (also why reposting/bad questions aren't well received). You may want to check your question objectively though. It's still a bit subpar for our quality

Comment: The second question was quite-correctly closed on the basis of the question itself. It's unclear, it doesn't have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as Carpetsmoker pointed out, it doesn't in fact even have any code, or a description of what tech you're using (other than Android), the tagging is all over the place (surely it doesn't really have any thing to do with the Android Debug Bridge), etc., etc.

Comment: Now that the new question has been deleted, if you're still having the problem, post a question taking into account the feedback above. Beware not to throw up a wall of code, but be clear, don't tag-spam, be specific about what tools you're using, exactly what you did, what the results were in test vs. live, etc. People **do** want to help. They really do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  This may be asking too much, but I really do not know how I could make a verifiable example for this. The problem itself involves none of my code (to my knowledge) as it just about using adb commands to back up data. The question itself seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: @HansPassant It may seem like playing the victim, but my original question was far worse than the revised one, got no up or downvotes. My far better one was immeditaley downvoted, along with the comment I mentioned above, I do think whether for right or wrong me 'reposting' had a large impact, at least to put my new question under far stricter scrutiny than normal.

Comment: Hmm, not so sure we do a good job of distinguishing horrible from bad questions.  The truly horrible ones tend to be ignored, usually because the title of the question is discouraging enough to stop anybody from looking at it in the first place.  That you actually got enough views on the second version to get it downvoted still does not make it a good question.

Comment: _"I really do not know how I could make a verifiable example for this"_ -- not all questions you can ask are questions that belong on Stack Overflow. If your question is so vaguely understood by you that you cannot create a suitable MCVE for it, it probably doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. There's a reason we have documents on Stack Overflow like [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

**Delete your question and post a new one.**

Sometimes a question isn't answered in a way that is helpful for others, but the answers are. In that case is preferable to improve the question, rather than delete it. Otherwise useful information as well as time and effort of others would be lost.

However if a question remains unanswered and it's ill constructed, there's no reason to keep it around. In fact, personally I'd vote such a question to be closed, rater than downvote it.

Comment: Also, a question should only be downvoted because of itself. Not because another question with similar content was posted and retracted before. The system already takes care of that if it happens repeatedly.

Comment: To add to this, if the question has answers, clearly isn't useful and should be deleted, but you can't delete it because it has answers... flag a moderator to delete it.