# Guidance when closing programming questions on Computer Science

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, question-quality

On [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), we have a close reason that reads

> Questions about **software development or programming tools** are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

That's not as helpful as it could be. CS.SE moderators can and do migrate questions that are in a good enough state to stand on Stack Overflow. We try to use a generic close reason for questions that are so far from being viable that we don't want to even suggest another site. So the primary target of that reason is people who've asked questions that could be suitable for Stack Overflow, but are not suitable in their current state, and who are going to read some short guidance. (We can't do anything about the ones who won't read the guidance anyway.)

What should we say? We have 400 characters including formatting.

In my experience, programming questions on CS mostly come into the following types, from most common to least:

1. Programming homework in computer science courses.
2. Programmers (students or not) who are “implementing an algorithm” and so feel that it's computer science, even if their problem is which library function to use or with the language syntax.
3. People who've read “computer” in the site name and didn't bother to think about the second word.
4. People who are blocked from asking on SO and try their luck elsewhere.

From this breakdown, I think that the main goal should be to drive people to write a complete question, with code and a clearly stated problem, while discouraging “do my homework”.

The goal of this meta question is to get experience from the Stack Overflow community as to what guidance to give for programming questions that are salvageable, but not suitable in their present state. Obviously we'll also be discussing this on [meta CS](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/better-guidance-for-our-belongs-on-stack-overflow-close-reason).

Comment: Are you looking for [auto-comments](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/blob/master/questions.md) or more extended guidance like [the checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)?

Comment: @rene I'm looking for something that would fit in a close reason.

Comment: one thing you sure do wrong is using the link to toothless ["about"](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page instead of much better one help/on-topic. Note how Programmers close reason [in the answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336525/839601) links to the help/on-topic page

Comment: Please note that _tool recommendation_ questions are off-topic on SO, while questions regarding _how to use_ programming tools are on-topic. This includes tools used when programming, such as compilers, linkers, debuggers, editors, IDEs, version control etc. But not "tools often used" by programmers, that is not PCs, web browsers, e-mail, MS Office, coffee machines... Tool recommendation questions can be re-directed to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Your close reason currently has two somewhat related points.

> Questions about **software development or programming tools** are off-topic here

You're telling the user that specifically "software development" and "programming tool" questions are off-topic on CS.SE. This is fairly straight-forward.

We can't really suggest a change to this part as we collectively don't have a sufficient average experience level with the your scope to judge the wording.

> but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

This is where it gets fuzzy. You're telling the user that all questions regarding software development or programming tools are on-topic for Stack Overflow, and should be asked there.

This guidance is hairy at best. Not all software development questions or questions regarding programming tools are on-topic here.

My suggestion is something along the lines of:

## 353 Chars

> Questions about **software development or programming tools** are off-topic here; however, questions regarding **specific programming problems** as defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or **the use of programming tools** for the purpose of programming *may* be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Raw:

> `Questions about **software development or programming tools** are off-topic here; however, questions about **specific programming problems** as defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or **the use of programming tools** for the purpose of programming *may* be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).`

Comment: I don't see how your wording clarifies anything. What kind of questions are you worried about that are about “software development” but are not about “the use of programming tools” nor about “specific programming problems”? By far the most common unsuitable-but-salvageable-by-asker questions are code dumps (ok with error messages and expected behavior), “my program to do X doesn't work” (ok with full code), and “plzsendtehcodez” (for which we try not to suggest another site at all).

Comment: It's not so much about the specific question that you're closing, it is about the guidance that you are instilling in the user for future reference. Currently you are saying "Your question is off-topic because it is ${question_type}, questions of about ${question_type} should be asked on Stack Overflow". What's to say that the next question the user is going to ask about ${question_type} is one of the ones that you would not redirect to another site? It's still a question about ${question_type}, and you told them that they should ask those questions here.