# Why was my question closed by the community after a moderator edited it?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047019/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-obtain-what-switch-port-a-computer-is-on). The question was regarding the "easiest" way to get the switch port number a computer is connected to.

I realize that easiest tends to be a buzzword around here for closing posts. However, in regards to working with [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) and gathering the information I'm looking for, I feel it's completely valid verbiage.

I got a comment by a community user that said

> Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a forum. Nor is it a library-recommendation site. "Easy" is an opinion. Please read How to Ask and the help center

At no point was I asking for a library recommendation. That user, in my opinion, was not following community guidelines regarding being kind to people who "may not know as much as you" and continued leaving non-constructive comments.

My post was edited by a moderator at some point who cleaned up some grammar and modified the body of my question as well as removing several of the comments left by both myself and the other community user. Within minutes of that edit, by a moderator who could have closed my question that instant, my post was closed by five community members, only one of whom has any serious mention of C# in their profile, for being "too broad". Additionally, the user who left the initial comment to my question is not a C# developer; he is a web developer.

Following the community guidelines for requesting a question be reopened I left a comment under the question asking it be reopened and stated my reasoning for why.

> I am requesting this question be re-opened for the following reasons. 1) At no point did my question violate any of the community guidelines. I did not ask for handouts, people to write my code, or for library recommendations. 2) I was not given a fair chance to get an answer as a user with much higher reputation than I left non constructive comments in my question and claimed I was asking for things posted in my first point. 3) My post I believe falls under the "Subjective Questions" section of What should I avoid posting as I'm looking for valid input from people who have tried this

I'm posting this question here for two reasons:

1. I would like any chance I can to get my question re-opened and answered.
2. I would like to understand why close votes aren't reset when a moderator edits a question.

Comment: I don't think those two actions were related.

Comment: The fact that a moderator removed some noise from your question doesn't mean they think it's a great question, or that it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: There's no reason to reset close votes just because a moderator saw or edited a question.

Comment: The comments you got weren't unconstructive at all.  You can of course disagree with them, but there was nothing inappropriate or not kind about them.

Comment: half of the comments are missing as they were removed when I flagged the comments as not constructive

Comment: The fact is that questions asking for lists/resources/the best approach to something rather broad/etc. are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. It's something that has developed over time, often in light of extremely prevalent problems associated with certain types of questions. In the olden days your question would have worked great. The community has become narrower and narrower in its focus. It's somewhat unfortunate but was perhaps unavoidable.

Comment: @Fancy_Mammoth You quoted a comment and said that it was inappropriate.  It is not inappropriate.  If there were other inappropriate comments that have since been deleted, then apparently that problem has been solved.

Comment: It's quite likely that Brad (the mod) didn't close your question _because_ it was about to be closed. He didn't need to step in and close it because the community already almost had it completely handled. As a side note, he did not "clean up grammar" in your post, he only removed the two irrelevant lines at the end of it.

Comment: wait.... how is the first comment not being nice? He explains concisely where your issue is, what stack isn't, and points you to a page that'll explain to you what happened...... Was it curt? yes, definitely. Not rude....

Comment: not constructive

Comment: Well... telling you "this isn't a site for this type of question, here is a page where you can learn more"... is actually constructive.... it guides you in learning the ropes.

Comment: Speaking as the "community user", and as I said in a later, deleted comment, I was trying to help you edit the question such that it would *not* be closed.

Comment: yeah, but it isn't answering his question! anything not answering his question isn't constructive and is absolutely rude! /s

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So you found your mistake I see.  Hopefully you won't make it again next time.  Trying to actually help someone; n00b mistake.

Comment: I give up. This site in so incredibly toxic its not even funny. Clearly based on my 23 reputation I'm new both to SO and development. I came here looking for valid answers and support and instead I've gotten nothing but negativity. What a great community you guys have here. It's pretty screwed up when somebody new is looking for valid information in an attempt to expand their own knowledge can't get it because they aren't a pro. Whatever toxic is toxic I give up. For a community with the intentions of helping people you failed pretty horribly today.

Comment: @Fancy_Mammoth okay...... you came here ranting and stomping your feet. As soon as someone tried to point out ANY kind of flaw, you answered with "not constructive". How is YOUR reaction not rude? (yeah you got some snark here... mainly in response to how YOU handle anything that is said... doesn't excuse it.. I'm just explaining). Meta is a tougher beast than stack to handle, but in general coming here and not listening is a good way to get something that looks toxic, yes. The site WORKS. you are new... give yourself the time (and chance) to learn it.

Comment: @Fancy_Mammoth You insulted people politely trying to help you.  *That* is being toxic.  The fact that you didn't get exactly what you wanted when asking a question that's not appropriate for the site, and instead were politely told that the question isn't appropriate, is not in fact "toxic".  Of course, that response has nothing to do with your rep; a 1 million rep user asking the same question would get the same response.

Comment: @Fancy_mammoth and the goal of stack is to establish a library of knowledge relating to programming. Helping people through Q&A is just the vehicle to get quality content up. It makes Stack weird at times, and VERY narrowly scoped. But learn the ways stack work and work WITH it... not against, as you are doing here :/

Comment: @Patrice he or she isn't really interested in an actual dialogue about what this place is, or anything else that doesn't confirm their preconceptions. Site doesn't help me, even insinuates my question isn't a good fit here = site sucks! No, I meant it's *toxic*. More modern

Comment: @Pekka웃 most likely true, but I am in a good, well rested mood today... so I feel like trying... it`s okay, I'll get back in a more cynical mode soon.... especially the way my last couple of tries have gone...

Comment: [And then they said: "For a community with the intentions of helping people you failed pretty horribly today."](https://cdn.meme.am/cache/images/folder558/7390558.jpg)

Comment: "Ah Meta, the place where users 'wronged' come to rant and rave, and throw words like _'toxic'_ and _'rude'_ our way. Be we patient or mean, no information they'll gleam, for we are wrong regardless of what we say. Dear users don't despair, for Meta does not care whether you think us demons or you think us unfair. When your rage has subsided, our advice has still been provided, so maybe you won't have to pull out your hair." - My true thoughts of Meta, in times such as this where users deem us toxic to our internet environment.

Comment: @Kendra I may steal that from you and use it elsewhere lol..... SOOOOOO appropriate.

Comment: @Patrice Feel free to reuse, all I ask is you link to my profile (Where that is totally going.) Edit: In profile and formatted, for all to use!

Comment: @Kendra I wouldn't think of NOT providing attribution, of course (you're making it easier. I won't try to keep it myself... I'll visit your profile when I want to post it, so I can't forget to attribute it ;) )

Comment: @Kendra - Very nice :D Somewhat related overmeta [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair/202912#202912)

Comment: Re "... is not a C# developer; he is a web developer ..."   [The web application we are using here is written in C#](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370)...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The sequence of events was this: I saw a bunch of flags on the comments due to the argument that was developing there. I cleaned that up to stop the argument from getting worse.

Because that argument was in part about your use of "discuss" at the end, coupled with a lack of a question mark anywhere in the question, I decided to fix at least that. I tried to give this a nudge back in a more targeted direction.

However, it did still look pretty broad to me, and was hard to tell if you were looking for a specific code-based solution or for a tool to do this. I could have single-handedly closed it, but I've found that people generally respond better to having a post closed by votes from their peers instead of a single person. It's much easier to get angry if you see one person's name on the close vote line than five people.

If it looks like the community is going to handle something well by themselves, I leave that to them and move on, which is what I did here.

It sounds like you're not coming back, but if you do, I'd learn from the responses you got and from the edit I made. People thought this was too broad, so maybe refine or narrow the scope a bit. They also weren't sure how this was a code-related problem, so perhaps explain in more detail how this would hook into your application. Open-ended discussions and solicitations of tools have traditionally led to problems in questions, which is why they are discouraged.

The issues with how this was presented were more communication problems than technical ones, which is why you don't need a background in C# to determine that this needed to be clarified.

Comment: Brad thank you for your answer. First and foremost I need to apologize for any negative behavior I dismayed. Admittedly I've had a rough week at work trying to get this application in building finished. Regardless it does not excuse any negative behavior. @MikeMcaughan my apologies to you as well for overreacting at your response rather than asking for advice on how to improve my post. I should have been more specific I understand that. Should I repost my question I will be sure to pay more attention to being more precise with my words. Again my sincerest apologies.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer to show that I understand my role in what occurred and in an attempt to quell any further discussion on this matter.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like any chance I can to get my question re-opened and answered.

That question was way too broad to be answered. On Stack Overflow I stick to what is on-topic and is of use for future visitors. Posts that don't meet that criteria will receive a close vote and delete vote from me.

You can use the [Question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to have an objective reference of the criteria for a good question.
Feel free to ask a question on meta if you need help shaping your question so it is on-topic and good enough to be both useful and answerable.

> I would like to understand why close votes aren't reset when a moderator edits a question.

Posts on Stack Overflow are moderated by the user community, like you and me. This means I edit, flag, down vote, close vote, and delete vote on posts that I feel are not up to the quality to be useful for future visitors. Moderators are exception handlers. That a moderator edits a post is by no means a signal that the community should stop moderating that post. If a moderator feels community  moderation is no longer needed they lock the post. This wasn't the case on your question.

Although it might look otherwise for you in this case, I really try to help make Stack Overflow that site with a collection of great questions and awesome answers. That does mean I close and delete vote a bunch of questions on a daily basis. I hope the provided link will help to get your next question to be better received.