# What's wrong with my post?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I just posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41981660) and instantly got downvoted.

I've been searching for solutions for 3 days and found nothing useful. I added some of the links I took a look at; it's not my first post and I always re-read before I post to see if my question is clear and simple. I also read once more ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and thought it was OK.

Can anyone explain me what is wrong with my question?

Comment: OK guys, this is getting nowhere. If you want to talk about **the content of the question and how to improve it**, then please do so. We've played out all these arguments many times before. Continue in [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134597/discussion-on-question-by-freddykong-whats-wrong-with-my-post) if you have to.

Answer (score 13):

It is very simple: On Stack Overflow for 99% of the time users are asking questions about practical coding problems.

That is why the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) has this question:

> If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?

and at best it should repeat that question a couple of times.

It is unclear where or how you invoke the WCF Client and what your interface looks like.

You don't show how you tried to apply the [`BinaryFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865123/578411) and what was failing in that attempt, nor did you explain how you tried to leverage [proto-buf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923451/578411). Proto-buf does have an extension that allows it to be integrated into the WCF pipeline but it is unclear if you have tried that.

So those attempts would have shown us where you have missed bits and pieces.

That the code you have is over 200 lines is not an excuse to leave the code out. I have never had my software fail at 200 lines at once. It somehow is always isolated to a single call/line and isolating that call and reproducing the conditions to make it fail (in an unit test for example) is a (major) part of your task as a developer. That is why I linked to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but the awesome [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) also wrote a great blog post about the same topic.

In conclusion: You have asked a question that left the users that can answer it with a lot of questions. The missing information shouldn't be provided on the go (*Don't hesitate to ask for details*) but be in the post from the start. That does require you spend (a lot of) time preparing your question, gathering all the research you did and your test results, so you can make sure that I or others can ideally copy/paste your code and drop it in an IDE to run/compile it.

If you want your question answered make sure there are no obstacles for the users to answer.

Your question was closed as too broad and down votes signaled correctly the quality issues with it. Now it is time for you to resolve those issues.

Comment: *"I have never had my software fail at 200 lines at once."* You should try writing multi-threaded code. :-)

Comment: When I grow up, I might ...

Comment: A good thing I try to do for my questions, and something that in this case would have benefited the OP I think: Keep your question draft open for a week (bear with me). Use that week to research on your topic. Whenever you find something new... add it to your draft. Once a day read your whole post and polish it. After a full week of this (adding references, polishing the Q, etc), either you will have found your issue yourself, and delete the draft (or keep it, post it, and self-answer it), or within that week, you have the most polished question you can have, that contains all your research

Comment: @Patrice A week might be a bit much, but yes, the sentiment is correct. The *worst* thing to do is *"I've banged my head against the wall for the past 3 days and I'm in a foul mood, Ima just rant off a post and throw it to SO."* – That's unlikely going to be a good post.

Comment: @deceze I like to be thorough, so I give myself a week. But yeah, not everyone will spend so much time on an issue, and that's fine. The approach is more important than the actual deadline here :P.