# Would anyone be able to help me to improve my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have written what is obviously a poor question (it is attracting downvotes):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127884/what-changes-should-be-made-to-the-linux-usb-driver-to-behave-as-an-hid

Would anyone be able to give me some guidance on how I could/should have written it to be a better fit for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Um, for starters, you could post the relevant portions of the code you've written. But even once that's done, it seems like this question is hopelessly too broad—you need to narrow down your problem more.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @CodyGray Agreed, should I go ahead and delete the question, or wait for it to be closed automatically now it is on hold?

Comment: "On hold" is a temporary status. The idea is that you should edit the question to fix the problems, and then the "hold" can be lifted. "On hold" eventually turns into "closed"—they are essentially the same thing, the software just uses a different word initially because it sounds nicer. If you want to delete it, you can. Or you can just fix it without having to re-ask.

Answer (score 8):

You're just asking way too much in a single question. As you start to work on the project and wrap around what you're going to need to do, you'll obviously hit obstacles (like your device not being seen as a HID even though you're sure the code you wrote should be working) - *that's* where we can help you.

We're very good with self-contained problems, one at a time, where a few paragraphs and perhaps some code are all that's needed to give you a great answer. You'll probably ask .. 10 or so questions while you work through your project, each one being about a very specific problem that you encountered.

What you've got is just too much with too little detail, and even if you provided a lot more detail, I'm not sure an answer would even *fit* in the maximum number of characters we allow :) That's the main problem.

Comment: OK, thanks - I do see what you're saying.  Someone actually left a really useful comment which made a great answer to the question (essentially pointing out that what I should be building was a USB Gadget driver), which is exactly the sort of help I was after to get me going.  I guess the question was seen as too broad because the problem I had was in understanding the higher level USB peripheral architecture, not it's lower level implementation.  Is there any way I can accept that as a valid answer to the question now that it is on hold?

Comment: I also see why @KenWhite suggested initially that it was posted to the wrong site - it really wasn't programming related if it was about the architecture & editing it to make about the code just made it too broad!