# Answered original of question duplicated by OP, how to proceed?

Tags: discussion

Two days ago, I answered a question to the best of my abilities. I did not receive any response on it, but thought I should give OP some time. Today, I was wondering if it would be appropriate to leave a comment asking if I answered the question. Thus, I browsed this site to find an answer and concluded that I should not. However, while doing so, I found something else.

Someone mentioned OP activity and this triggered me to check this for OP. This lead to me discovering that OP asked the almost exact same question I had answered some time later. It got answered a mere 20 minutes before I answered their original question.

The new question has a more generic title, but the contents are practically the same. I believe that the two questions are duplicates of each other.

The accepted answer on the new question is excellent, but the answer I have provided is I think better in this specific instance, because it is more efficient (not *all* combinations have to be considered). In that sense, I believe both answers have value for the duplicated question.

What would be the best course of action for me to take now?

- Should I flag the new question as a duplicate of the old one?
  This seems unfair as the new question is set up slightly more generically. It also received some high quality answers.
- Should I flag the old question as a duplicate of the new one?
  This seems not quite right because the more specific question makes it so that a more efficient solution can be deployed.
- Should I not undertake any action?
- Should I do something I have not thought of?

Related question: is cross-posting my answer acceptable in this case? It feels wrong to me to do such a thing, but then again this seems to be an exceptional case.

Comment: This is not an exceptional case, new user repost questions every 20 minutes. Most of the time, op does not attract any valuable answer. So flagging duplicate, is an easy choice. But in this case a moderator flag to merge the 400% duplicate question seems a good choice.

Comment: Downvoting and pointing out in a comment that repeatedly posting the same question is not encouraged is also an option.

Comment: Comment pro-forma for pointing out the issue to op: Please don't re-post your questions; our community often sees this as badgering. We'll now have to close your post as a duplicate, and multiple closed questions can lead to a question ban. If you want to draw attention to your question, see [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights. I was not aware that it is so common, sorry. I will comment and flag for moderator attention as you suggested.

Comment: This case wasn't a mere repost of a question, though. First the OP posted a *bad* question with a huge code dump and a highly-localised problem that would never be useful to others. Fine, downvote it. Then they realised that they could extract out a more succinct, more generic question, without the huge code dump, that had some chance of being useful to future visitors. Rather than edit their existing question and invalidate @Justastudent's answer, they posted a new, better one. That was *exactly the right thing to do*, and shouldn't have been punished by downvotes in the way that it has been.

Comment: @MarkAmery I would agree with you, but note that the question was reposted well (about 2.5 hours) before I answered the original question. At that point, editing would have been better. My answer does apply to the new question and would not have been invalidated by the edit.

Comment: @Justastudent ah, I hadn't taken note of the timings. You're right, that changes things. I disagree that your answer wouldn't be invalidated, though; the second post doesn't explicitly mention "coalitions" anywhere, and your answer uses the term constantly, so it'd be quite confusing to anyone who hadn't seen the first question.

Comment: @MarkAmery Fair enough, I would have to edit my answer to not use that term, but in its core, it would still apply. I would in fact be happy to make my answer suitable for the second question (and may have to do so when the questions are merged, not sure how that works).

Comment: @Justastudent unfortunately, looking at the close votes (which I don't think you can see at your rep level, but I can), it looks like the closure is going to end up happening in the wrong direction - with the better question getting closed and the worse one sticking around. What a mess!

Comment: @MarkAmery Indeed I cannot see those and it was definitely not my intention to have it balance out like that...

Comment: @MarkAmery has understood the problem. If people could help me with the generic part of the problem in the second question, I thought I could take those answers to the older, more detailed question and then narrow down the issue to a point where everyone could understand. Nina Scholz, however, already understood how the democratic system in Holland works and gave me a good answer. Therefore, both questions stayed where they were and now my reputation is going to sh*t for a small mistake I usually don't even make. I'm not new to this community, I know the rules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vote to close (or, if you don't yet have enough rep, flag) one question as a duplicate of the other. The least good of the two questions should be flagged, so that it can act as a signpost pointing to the best of the two.

In addition, we are encouraged to downvote questions that are not useful. What constitutes a "not useful" question is open to some interpretation. In my view, a duplicate question posted by the same user definitely qualifies as not useful.

Posting a constructive comment indicating that posting duplicate questions is a bad thing to do is also an appropriate additional action.

Answer (score -16):

I am the OP @Just a Student is talking about and it's clear he hasn't understood my intentions. I've also stated why I reposted the question in the comments, but this isn't being mentioned.

The reason I re-asked the question in a more generic manner is because this question was related to an application meant for the 2017 elections in The Netherlands. As you know, many democratic countries have completely different democratic systems/structures. My first question was very detailed and also mentioned many things about the Dutch election system, so some people got confused and asked questions related to the elections to better understand the question (because there are many people here who are not from Holland). This made me realise that if I had asked the question in a more generic way, people wouldn't be confused with all the elections related stuff.

The OP must have seen that I received a perfect answer from Nina Scholz, and that's why I didn't respond to his answer as it didn't fix my problem.

I'm grateful to Just a Student for the time he spend on helping me, and I know it's not nice to double post questions. The reason I left the older one is because I didn't expect someone (in this case Nina Scholz) to understand the whole thing and give me the exact right solution after reading the generic question. Therefore, I could get a more generic answer from the generic question, add those details to the older question as an addition and then delete the generic question. Things just didn't go as I expected.

To be clear, both questions were not identical. One question explained the democratic system in Holland and the other was just a simple way to get me started.

I see many downvotes on both questions as people here just jump to conclusions and feel the need to punish me for what I did. Well, congrats :) You did what you thought you had to do.

@Just a Student: I understand you got agitated because I didn't respond to your answer. It simply didn't fix my problem. I did accept your answer for you and upvoted it, if it makes you feel better.

*EDIT
I made both questions identical now, to make sure that if one gets deleted, the contents of the generic question remain. Hopefully, Nina's answer can also be moved to the question that won't be deleted.

Comment: I downvoted your second question, but not because of the reasons you assume. The questions sounds like a typical "Write my code for me" question, not showing any code or any effort you tried to solve the problem. It's basically just a definition of input and output, looking for a programmer to drop by and write a solution for you.

Comment: @EricAya Well if someone feels so offended he/she has to come here to complain and draw attention here because I didn't respond, and then my rep goes down because of that, I need to do something right? I've removed my acceptance from his answer now as it's just not helpful to me, but this is just absurd.

Comment: I want to stress that I did *not* intend what is happening at the moment. I also did not get agitated at all, as I state in the question here I stumbled upon your other question and was genuinely unsure of what to do. Hence this question. Sure, I would have appreciated a comment explaining why my answer does not help you, because I am glad to improve my answer. I also think that my answer gives you the same results as Nina's answer does. But that was *not* the reason why I posted this question and I sincerely hope that you can see this. I wish that I could undo the downvotes for you...

Comment: To further add: I think the answer of Nina Scholz is very good, but answers your first question instead of the second one. When just stumbling over the second question, terms like seats, parliament etc. only make sense if you know the election system in your country. I would really appreciate it if we could move the answer to the first question where it would perfectly fit.

Comment: @Justastudent I understand, and like I said I'm really grateful for the time you put into helping me, as I wouldn't be able to help with such a big and complicated question myself. If this wasn't your intention, then there's no problem if my rep even goes down to 0 ;). It's just sad that other members of the community just hit the downvote button without looking at the story from the other side, like people are just looking for the tiniest of excuses to downvote stuff. Strict moderation is one thing, but this wave of downvoting has even surprised you, so what can I say?

Comment: @erol_smsr, again, most downvoters are just voting on the quality of the questions themselves. The meta effect is simply amplifying the natural course of events.

Comment: @yivi The natural course of events is not downvoting questions without at least thinking about my intentions. Not everyone here is trying to screw up this site by double posting everything. Sometimes, even experienced members make mistakes or get misunderstood. But, here on SO there is no time or space for misunderstandings or honest mistakes, obviously. But that's just the way it is I guess. It remains the most useful site for things like this.

Comment: Most people have good intentions when they post a question but that can't prevent a question from getting downvotes if needed.

Comment: @erol_smsr, I'm sorry, but "your intentions" are not terribly relevant to voting, in general. The **post** is. If your post is not considered useful by the community, you may get downvotes. No biggie.

Comment: Read on this [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), or about what a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is; and you may see why some people might have considered your question less than good.

Comment: @JoeW Yes, like you said: 'if needed'. Some people here and myself are now worried that SO will delete the question that contains Nina's correct answer and leave the question that doesn't have a correct answer (partially incorrect). So, all this downvoting may result in the opposite of what people try to achieve by downvoting stuff.

Comment: You still assume that you get downvoted because of the double-posting. What, in my oppinion, has happened is, that you post got a lot of views and a lot of people (including me) thought that the question itself is bad. That's why they downvote. Having a good answer is also not a reason for not downvoting an answer. Although I completely agree that the answer of Nina should be preserved as answer to the first question.

Comment: That's weird, because until Just a Student posted this post here, there was nothing going on. So maybe you are one of the people who just looked at the question and didn't find it useful. Fair enough. But the other 10/20 downvotes came after this story was posted here.

Comment: I also stumbled over the question through this thread. And my downvoting also happened after this story was posted. This still doesn't mean that people downvote because of the post here, it just means you got a lot more attention through the meta post.

Comment: That's what is called the "meta effect".  Your post got a lot more attention than would have gotten otherwise. Still, that doesn't take merit from the downvotes. The downvotes are (IMO), deserved. If you got away with a bad question (like so many others before and after), it was just you getting lucky.

Comment: @erol_smsr Welcome to Meta, where we have our famous [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). SO gets tons of questions a day, but Meta is to questions  like a [laser pointer is to cats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUlFTudQ22o). All that happened was more people than normal viewed your question

Comment: @Machavity I see. I'll be more careful when asking questions in the future then.

Comment: Also, don't take this badly. If you use this as a learning experience, you'll regain the rep points lost today in no time. Because your future questions will be much better. Everybody wins! :)

Comment: I don't really care about the rep number, I just don't want to get a ban just because of a small honest mistake/misunderstanding. From now on, I'll make sure I don't make the same mistake. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Communication is crucial.

Comment: This worries me: "Therefore, I could get a more generic answer from the generic question, add those details to the older question as an addition and then delete the generic question."  Deleting a question should be a response to finding out it is off-topic, not something you plan on from the beginning.  If you get an answer that helps you write your next question better, it should still be left on the site so others can read and learn from it as well.