# Question wait time bug?

Tags: support, post-ban, rate-limiting

[image: The Message I get]I was told yesterday by the system I couldn't ask any more questions because I had already asked too many, and that I would have to wait one day. I have come back today, and I apparently still need to wait one day. Is this a bug?

Yesterday it said I had waited 0 days since my last question, and to wait one day. Now it says I have waited one day, and to wait one day. This is very frustrating, as I have a lot of questions since I'm still learning coding.

Edit: It's now been a whole day, a full 24 hours, and I still can't post.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the message. Based on your text it is unclear if you're rate-limited or question banned.

Comment: You asked your most recent question 23 hours ago. That is less than a day.

Comment: @MartinSmith Why does it say it's been a day then? Does it just round, or is this a bug?

Comment: No idea, could be rounding or because it is a different UTC day perhaps.

Comment: *Now* it has been over 24 hours. Do you still see the same message?

Comment: Let me give you one advice, based on your *This is very frustrating, as I have a lot of questions since I'm still learning coding.* sentence. The warning you see now is to prevent that you will get yourself question banned. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/) and the linked/related questions on that question to make sure you fully understand on which track you are. Also helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes

Comment: You'll see this message for another 6 hours or so. You are under a timed question ban, which is *not good*. You need to make sure you do a better job of asking questions that are valuable not just to you, but to other visitors as well. Take the opportunity to study [ask] until then.