# Why was my question downvoted, and did I not get any reasons?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

So, recently I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455506/eclipse-suddenly-doesnt-recognise-my-imports-or-anything-anymore), which immediately got downvotes. I asked why, multiple times, but no-one seemed to be bothered to answer that. I get the normal reasons for downvotes, and why questions would be bad, but I have no idea which of these reasons apply to my question. It obviously isn't a duplicate or anything like that. It's not like I did not do any research to fix it myself. So what in particular makes it worth downvotes?

If there is something wrong with my question, I would love to know. I really want to improve my question, but having no reason as to why it is bad, there is nothing I can do to improve it.

Comment: You might find the [Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) handy to use before you post a question. If used correctly it should fix any possible immediate down vote reasons before being posted.

Answer (score 10):

Many of the downvotes probably occurred before you added the necessary extra information to the question. You got downvotes because it took so many iterations for people to understand exactly what the problem was.

The fact that it had to be edited to remove expletives and fix the language also may have contributed.

If you want help you need to be polite, informative and clear. To being with, when you started, you were not. People voted on what they saw.

<sub>(This is just a view from the side. I have not previously been involved in that question.)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The original question was very badly worded and reads more like a rant then a genuine question.

> what the fuck is going on

and

> boom, eclipse had gone crazy

are just two examples that add no information or value whatsoever to the question. Those two alone, paired with not much tangible information, may have contributed to downvotes.

The question still isn't very clear. the very first image is cropped so heavily that its impossible to see the selection.

Next, its not really clear what the question is about. You seem to have two distinct problems. At first the question is about not being able to run a certain program, then suddenly the question shifts to not being able to import classes. What is it, then?

At present, it doesn't look like a good Q&A question. Those images should probably get transscripts so that the error messages can be indexed. In fact, if you had run a search for

> "string cannot be resolved to a type" eclipse

you would have found several questions on SO which might resolve your issue, e.g. [Java project in Eclipse: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind) and [My copy of Eclipse doesn't know what an object or a String is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796464/my-copy-of-eclipse-doesnt-know-what-an-object-or-a-string-is)

Since this never shows up as *text* in your question, future readers, potential answerers and you are not able to work with the error message and thus unable to find references. Thats yet another reason to downvote the question. If you have seen those questions, then you *must* mention it in the body of your question and explain *why* those do not apply (the question might even get closed as duplicate otherwise).

tl:dr; The question isn't all that helpful and not well crafted in the grand scheme of things. I haven't voted on it, but I'd probably downvote it too if I had encountered it in the wild.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that the language maybe wasn't that ideal, and its probably because at that point I had been trying to fix it for a few hours and was just really frustrated with it. I will try and edit my question to make it better. That is the only thing I want, but it also was very frustrating to me that people downvoted it but I had no idea how I could improve.

Comment: I edited my question, and I hope its better now.