# How can I make my questions more helpful?

Tags: discussion

I've been actively using SO for a few weeks now, but that still means I'm relatively new to the practices used here. That said, I do know that SO is community based, and that if I'm asking a question, there's probably others out there trying to ask the same question. It stands to reason that if I didn't find an answer to that question, then others could have trouble finding those answers, too.

With that in mind, I try to make my questions helpful not just for myself, but for anyone else looking for those answers. I try to be concise, I try to provide all relevant information, and I try very hard to make my questions answerable - though sometimes I do fail at these endeavors.

So, since I am trying to help not just myself, but also anyone else who stumbles across my questions, what are some ways that I can make my questions more helpful for myself and others?

Comment: That is bit broad. Did you visit the help center? [check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [meta-tag:faq]'s about the topic?

Comment: don't ask *"What are the best (and worst) ways to ..."*

Comment: Don't post code from your application.  Instead, isolate the issue in a MCVE and use that in your question. It helps to generalize and clarify the problem, making it easier to recognize for users with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the only things we can ask you to do is:

- Be clear about your problem,
- Include as many details as you can (including stack traces - those always come up in searches),
- Be concise with what problem you're attempting to address, and
- Be sure that you've done your due diligence on research; if a duplicate question comes up and you're certain it isn't a dupe, then leave details specifying why that is.

In *general* this is also how the community votes on questions, but if you're also looking for a question for others to look for, then this aligns with it too.