# Overzealous automatic deletion

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44235801/4376309) was automatically deleted because it got -2 votes (no reasons were given) and no answers within 30 days. I believe that the problem was well-explained and researched. I also believe that, if solved, it will provide value to the community (i.e. an Apple-endorsed boids flocking behavior in both Swift & Obj-C).

Note that the downvotes occurred before I edited the question. Granted, the question was probably unclear before the edits. I feel that I clarified it sufficiently with editing. But people who downvote are unlikely to revisit a question, yet the harm is done. The automated deleter will eventually remove a question that has negative votes without considering that the question may have been improved since it was downvoted.

It seems to me that automatic deletion should wait until negative votes have reached a significant number before removing a question. Or wait longer before deleting. Or some other considerations should be made by the process to account for questions that may have been initially bad but were subsequently edited and improved.

Comment: It is back... (undeleted)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It seems to me that automatic deletion should wait until negative votes have reached a significant number before removing a question.

-2 *is* a significant number.

If we can't delete even -2 voted questions, we might as well scrap the entire bot.

That this sometimes harms posts that get edited into shape after downvoting is unfortunate - that a post that has once been downvoted rarely manages to recover is a well known fact.

Unfortunately, right now, there is no other remedy to that than to make super sure it's a workable question from the start. (I realize that isn't always easy.)

I don't think your question is a  perfect SO question yet even with your edits, though. It could use some more work.

Personally, I'd post the question again, making sure it contains a clear, *specific*  technical question rather than just "something is off here".

Ideally, you'd accompany that with detailed debugging results, showing when and how the position of your spaceships differs from those in the video.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I agree that the question still has flaws (although I see many questions that are similar or more flawed which persist on SO). I may try to work on the question some more and repost as you suggested. My specific question aside, it seems desirable to improve the roomba to give additional consideration to questions that were edited and may have been improved since receiving downvotes.

Comment: I recognize that you tried to do the right thing and edit, but he question went from "translate my code <DUMP>" to "fix my code <DUMP>". In neither case is there a specific, clearly articulated coding issue that can be concisely resolved with a solution that'll be found and used by other people.

Comment: @peacetype use the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and remember that list is not a menu you can pick items from, instead you should only post if all items in the list are sufficiently  addressed in your post.

Comment: @rene Thanks for the tip. I just edited the post to isolate what I suspect is the problematic part of the code. I left the GitHub link there so people have access to all of the code.