# Can I ask novice level questions on Stack Overflow if I can't find the answer by googling?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm an IT apprentice and am currently learning to program. Obviously, I have a lot of questions, some of which the answers to are hard to research.

I've been posting these question on Stack Overflow and although I usually got an answer I have also been told that I'm asking them in the wrong place as they are often more general questions or I'm looking for recommendations. So where can I go for such questions or should I keep posting them on Stack Overflow?

Comment: As long as you follow the rules of SO, how to ask, etc. and you have attempted your own research, then any level of question is acceptable. of course for SO it has to be programming related, there are different sites for hardware or software practices.

Comment: _they are often more general questions or I'm looking for recommendations_. In that case, they are offtopic and you should definitely not ask them in SO. _Novice/Beginner level_ questions can be on topic provided they follow the rules in the help center

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. At least run your question through a spell checker

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a goto site for the general questions or recommendations?

Comment: Do you have an example of such a question? If you looked for an answer, couldn't find it and can ask an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question then please do.

Comment: @Oleg For example if i dont know which approach to tackle a problem with in a situation where there seem to be multiple valid ones. Or in a situation where i dont know what to look for / where to begin in handling my issue.

Comment: In most cases this will probably be of-topic(opinion based), something like that you can ask on softwareengineering site(probably, not sure about what rules they have).

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: When you need to do X and you've identified three ways to accomplish it, you're better off prototyping them rather than asking some random stranger on the internet to tell you what to do.

Comment: Ask yourself: what are the chances that no one else experienced this problem or had this question before me? If there is any chance that you're not first, please keep searching. Use different search terms. Check spelling. Try looking for terminology first. Use a different search engine, use SO search, type in your question and look at the links suggested by SO. When you're new to coding, asking an SO question should be really the last thing you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, the [type of questions you are talking about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/can-i-ask-novice-level-questions-on-stackoverflow-if-i-cant-find-the-answer-by-g#comment518623_357307) are likely to be off-topic / opinion based.

If you are working in a team environment, these are the type of questions you should be directing at more senior members of your team either directly or during a code review.

If you are willing to learn, more senior developers should be open to a request if you ask them to review a piece of your code and they will be able to explain, with problem context, why approach *X* is better than approach *Y*.

Comment: For code reviewing questions, one should also take a look at [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).