# Is there any limit of questions in a post?

Tags: support

Can I ask multiple questions in a single post (here multiple means 5 or 6)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are the questions closely related? Maybe give an example.

Comment: I have around 6 tables and 6 questions based on them . I do not want to ask 6 questions separately because they all are dependent on these tables . So can i include my  6 questions in a single post so the?

Comment: The [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) uses singular throughout so that is best followed. One post, one question, so one answer can focus on a single issue.

Comment: Better to first search the StackOverflow site for similar questions *before* asking, since it's very rare that your current problems are new.

Comment: Yes. The limit is 1.

Comment: [A link to the post this question is relating to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488686/sql-server-tricky-questions)

Comment: I think it's great for you that you didn't take my or EzLo's word and went to ask on Meta. I really mean it, this is not sarcasm.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Asking multiple questions in a single post is the sole reason my questions were not answered by great developers ! Fine  let me ask one at a time and see.

Comment: Again, you may be misunderstanding what this site is for. This is less a help site and much more a question and answer (q/a) repository. Help can occur as a by product of the latter. Again this site is much better used as a searchable repository, and I'd venture that 99% of your questions can best be answered by doing this, by searching, deeply, first, before asking. Only ask after doing this extensive research and be sure to show the concrete fruits of your efforts in your questions since otherwise your question may risk being closed and down-voted for lack of research.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels SO is definitely a help site though. Its not as if people come here to ask questions they don't need help with or primarily ask questions they know the answer to for the benefit of the site. People ask questions they need help with, if the questions are deemed good by the community- they stay and help developers with the same issue in the future. Rules are harsh compared to other sites but it still serves to help users.

Comment: @chevy, I'm not saying that the site doesn't help users, just that when it does, it's a secondary benefit not a primary. If the site were primarily a help site, we wouldn't be voting on question quality or closing questions. Too many new members are disappointed with their experience with the site just because their assumptions on the purpose of the site are incorrect

Answer (score 13):

A question should be just that, a *single* question.

You should not ask multiple questions in a question. Questions containing multiple questions can be closed as *too broad*.

Questions should be answered with a single answer, and if a question is in fact multiple questions, then an answer might answer one of those, but not others, and that leads to a mess...