# What can you do if someone claim a simple search can yield the answer and you disagree?

Tags: discussion

When I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750566/let-r-access-outlook-mailing-list?noredirect=1#comment88516451_50750566) (which is now on hold), a user commented this is solvable by a simple SO or google search. I actually did search before I post but couldn't find any answer, so in the comment I asked that user to give me some example of search result.

I asked this because (1) maybe I am wrong, a simple search does yield the answer, but more because (2) I do not believe a simple search can yield something useful.

The original commenter did not respond by providing any example links. But I see that my comment asking for links attracted a lot of vote to put the question on hold, quoting the reason that asking for off-site resources is off-topic.

This seems quite unfair to me because I did not ask for any off-site resource in the question itself, and even the request in the comment is a response/challenge to someone claiming the existence of such resources.

I understand we do not want to encourage questions that can be answered by a simple google search. But on the other hand, when someone claim a simple search can yield the desired result (and vote down your question as a result of that), I feel that that the burden of proof is now with that person.

So, what can I do when I disagree with someone claiming a simple search can yield the result?

(asking for proofs attracted 'off-topic' votes)

Comment: I was able to find this: [Sending email in R via outlook](//stackoverflow.com/q/26811679) in less that 4 minutes of searching, but I don't know enough about R to say if it helps.

Comment: Your question is not terribly unusual lately, falls in the category of "I want to write a program but have no idea how to get started".  Which is utterly unanswerable, we don't know what you don't know.  You claim it is only 10% but we can't see the 90%.  You are getting a bit of push-back from an SO contributor that is miffed about questions like that, he has no idea why you thought it was a good question to ask.  It wasn't of course.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually he didn't say he is only missing 10%.  He appeared to be summarizing questions containing code that way, and thinking that because his circumstance is missing 100% was a good reason not to post code.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks for the search, but no, it does no help. That result is about sending email via R. My question is about accessing the mailing list using R. And I suspect the claim about a quick search can yield the result is based on this kind of search which doesn't really help. But I still thank you because at least you attempted to show some evidence.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I think your comment is illuminating. It seems to me that many people is obsessed with seeing a code block in the question. So I will try to ask the question again with a code block, hoping this time it will pass the test.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I find it amusing that someone upvoted your comments. You did a legitimate search, but the result is not useful (as I have tried before I posted my question). Why would someone upvote a non-useful result? This indicates the upvoter don't actually understand R or what I am trying to do. And this really proves my point. The downvoter needs to prove that they actually know what they are saying when they claim they can find an answer by a quick search.

Comment: @qoheleth: Your situation pretty much boils down to "You're using the wrong tool for the job".  R is designed for manipulating data.  When you want to do something totally different, like interprocess communication, you should not do it IN R, you should write an R library / loadable module in another language that can perform the task, which meets your goal of getting the results back to R for further processing.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is a valid response, and much better than just quickly dismissing the question as too easy because a quick search can yield the answer. As for this meta question: Suppose it is the case that it is impossible to do (easily) in R, then someone came and claim that a quick search yield the answer, what would you suggest I do?

Comment: @qoheleth: I would suggest you re-read the comment more carefully.  "42" did not claim your answer was easy to find using a search, he said "You are expected to do your own searching first. **Then write up what's not working for you**."   Your edit, highlighting the difference between sending an email and reading the address book, is a step in the right direction.  Every thing you attempted and write two sentences explaining why it didn't work out saves time for literally thousands of other users who find and read your question and might try the same futile approach.

Comment: Remember there are two ways that questions get answered on SO.  For common problems, you'll find an expert who already knows the answer and can just give it to you.  (It's still important to show your attempt, because that tells them what level of detail they need in their explanation). For niche problems (which yours certainly is), it's very unlikely someone has done it before, but you may just find someone who has done things related enough to put them together after some significant trial and error. Your responsibility is to share what you've already done to minimize the time it costs them.

Comment: For example, I'm pretty sure I could pull this off in the scientific tool of my choice (Matlab), because I have experience writing C++ MEX functions, calling them from Matlab, I have a strong suspicion that MAPI is the right OS API for access to the Outlook address book, and I've plenty of experience reading API documentation and writing C++ code to use it.  It still would take me several hours to put together.  So I can point you in the direction of following the same path with R, but I don't write R libraries using C++ and don't use R enough to know how to call a custom library function.

Comment: @qoheleth: Reviewing the more recent comments left at your main question -- If you would have shown that you have code for accessing the Outlook "Application" object, and said you were stuck getting from there to the address book, I would know that I just need to help you through the Outlook OLE Automation object model docs (it looks like you want `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists` or `Application.Session.AddressLists`) and the fact I don't know how to make R packages doesn't matter.   See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/addresslist-object-outlook

Comment: A type library and COM obejct viewer viewer would have helped.  R, C++, C#, whatever, COM is essentially all the same.  You found a COM interface library for Outlook and then...just stopped and posted an endless loop round SO main and meta, trying to get others to provide links.  COM nearly always requires, well, actual research work - you know, that thing where you try stuff and change/fix it until it does something useful.

Comment: @qoheleth Do you understand how that comment comes across? Someone did some research for you that could help you in the right direction. You hadn't put that in your question before I posted, so how would I know you had seen it previously and dismissed it? Then, after someone tries to help, do you thank them for at least trying to help? No, you say that *I should have done more research to help you*. Seems kind of an entitled position to come from, no?

Answer (score 14):

Let me take some of the first bullets of the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

- Have you done some research before asking the question?

Answering that question with yes, isn't enough. You searched for something that didn't render results, so share what you searched for and what you looked at:

> I searched for *Foo* and found [FooBar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) but that explains how I get bar. I'm looking for a way to get the Foo

expand for other sources you find. Include how you tried to incorporate the offered options in your context and how it failed.

Sharing your research like that helps those that want to answer tremendously because they can either skip the most trivial options or they can zoom in on a particular aspect you overlooked.

- Have you explained what you've already tried to solve your problem?

While you use paragraphs of texts to convince the readers some options don't work for you, why don't you show it?

> I found BarFoo but when I called BarFoo![GetFoo] it didn't return a list and not a Foo.

- If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?

Your question reads to me as you expect the answer to be some code. While it is not mandatory I'm personally much more inclined to put some effort in if I have a ready to run code example I can lift from the question. It either allows me to verify your findings, adapt and extend or even get the confirmation that you're on the wrong track.

tl;dr; Don't forget we're not in your shoes, we don't know the bigger picture you're trying to solve, we don't know your skill level, we can't see your browsing history, we don't have access to your IDE or PC or the dustbin that collected the dismissed attempts to solve your issue. You have to provide that in your question so we don't have to make the exact same journey you made. Instead we only have to extend on what you already know or put you on a track you missed. And yes, the burden to write the perfect question is totally on you