# Where do I ask questions about plugins for a framework?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Because a question ***"Is there a plugin for X in Jquery"***, is apparently off topic on Stack Overflow, and also off topic at "Software Recommendations". There is technically no place in this site to ask questions like this. So, someone wiser than me, please suggest where to ask these type of questions. If you were to know "is there a control to, say, create an analog clock", which place would you go?

Because that "minimal, verifiable, complete" FAQ doesn't tell me so.

Comment: I mistakenly closed this. It's on topic for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation

Answer (score 7):

You would ask these *questions* on your favorite search engine like:

- Google
- Bing
- DuckDuckGo

they will return a few pages with links to various resources, including plugins. You try a couple of the suggestions and then you can ask on Stack Overflow:

> I'm implementing an analog clock by using the [TicToc](https://tictoc.example.com) plugin but I need the clock to go anti-clockwise. I tried the `options` but that didn't work. I also looked at the plugin [YAC](https://yac.example.com) and [SuperWatch](https://sw/example.com) but those seem more limited. How can I have the clock go anti-clockwise? (I'm not bound to use TicToc)

I imagine answers to this question either solves your problem at hand OR suggests you a different plugin that meets your requirement.

#### But, there is a complete site dedicated to software recommendations

That is correct, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) exists and in its [What is on topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) they state that the:

> site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task ... this includes software libraries for development use

And they continue later on with:

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
>   Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

and in [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) it is explained what is minimal expected for a recommendation question to be successful answered on that site. And that needs more than just a rough idea.

#### I know nothing

If you can't Google or formulate an objective requirement set, you're unlikely to find an answer by means of asking a question on any Stack Exchange site. If there is a toolstack specific [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) you can try such room or alternatively a more *traditional* forum (reddit, quora, Askquestions.tech spring to mind) where the format is more unstructured to nurture wild idea generation.

---

<sub>The shown question is a very minimal example and still below par. Apply the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to make sure any question is in good shape before being posted</sub>

Comment: That would work if say plugin can be found. If I can't find a plugin, or not even know if it exists, what then? Or say I want to know an equivalent control to something that exists in different framework? For example, equivalent of grid view in PHP? Again, it is an example, not that I need to find gridview.

Comment: That kind of question is simply off topic on Stack Overflow. There are other sites where asking such questions are on topic: for example, I expect Yahoo Answers would allow you to ask the question, and I'm sure there's a subreddit that exists that welcomes questions such as those. As rene has pointed out, using your favorite search engine to search is always a good first step.

Comment: @jitendragarg _If I can't find a plugin, or not even know if it exists_ - Well, for starters, search on your favorite search engine about it. That's called _research_, which happens to be a [very very big part](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5827005) of asking questions on Stack Overflow.