# How do you best research your question before asking it on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, question-quality

I've been wondering if there are some research tips before asking something on SO. I know this questions seems dumb but think about it. How do people get to know an answer by researching and the person asking the question couldn't get said answer.

Are there some sites which are good besides SO? Is there a better search engine than google? How do you guys research before asking a question?

I've read the article on how to ask good questions, I wonder about how to best research the question you have.

I'd love to hear your input so we (new SO community) won't ask so many duplicate questions. How can I be sure the question isn't somewhere out there in the internet?

Comment: Knowing the right search terms is key. Problem is, that's the hardest part. Most people don't realize this, which is why I find criticism of "lack of research effort" quite disproportionate at times.

Comment: How do you get the right search terms? Are you just trying different combinations of words? @BoltClock

Comment: I don't have much of an answer for that. Sometimes I'm able to find the right terms by first searching for a different set of terms which then leads me to the right ones. Other times it can take prior knowledge of a deceptively unrelated topic altogether.

Comment: This question is way too broad imo. How to research really depends on what you want to research (type of question, programming language, etc.)

Comment: Well it also depends of the type of question for exemple for debugging question, the proccess of making a [mcve], and the classical debugging process are often enought to clear minor mistake. But you can't ask in term that you don't know. But let's be clear. That's a good thing! Duplicate are a good thing especially sane duplicate. Because Asker reformulate the question so other will find the right answer.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It totally is. All I'm asking is if there are some hidden, ulterior websites or even tips regarding the research of a peremptorily topic.

Comment: It is true that sometimes finding the right search terms is hard. However, more often than not, simply entering the title of the question into Google is enough to pop the answer as the first result. These are the ones we get annoyed about. If you go like "I have a 2d array and i want to add to every element the sum of its neighbours but multiplied with these other values", I'll be more than happy to hint "look up 2d convolution"; there's no shame in failing to find that. If you ask "how to write bubble sort in python", [aaaaargh!](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+to+write+bubble+sort+in+python)

Comment: Many times, just thinking about how an _ideal_ answer could look is enough to help you writing a better question, and to think of better ways to research your problem.

Comment: Voting to Leave Open. There's a potential FAQ in here, and good answers will provide great resources for new users.

Comment: @SeeSharp I've retracted my last comment and close vote, though, the problem with things like this post is that the advice given is very much not localized. For some languages, you should just look in the docs for code examples, for others _the docs_ is a $300 document that's not made to be understood by beginning programmers. Just reading the tag wiki will often provide better guidance than a _catch-all_ answer here. And for the basics, just see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the links provided there. Overly general and long answers waste time imo.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth No one forces anyone to read anything on this site. It's here to provide information and if these answers help someone they should just stay where they are.

Comment: No-one's forcing me. But the point is, if this gets to be a faq, it will be referred to by others when closing questions/providing guidance/etc., especially since it's so general you can slap it on any question without worrying if it might not be appropriate. So this Q&A might be harmful for SO as a whole, even though it may be helpful to some.

Comment: See also [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Just add `site:stackoverflow.com` to your google search.

Answer (score 17):

### Debug and construct a minimal example

If you have a problem with code that isn't working, you should start by debugging it and breaking it down to the smallest possible program that reproduces the issue.

This may either:

- Just solve your issue, thus you don't ask a question.
- Give you a smaller program to post, which focuses on the specific issue, which is easier to answer and more useful for future visitors.

These are really 2 separate steps, but they can be rather intertwined - sometimes it's just one or / and then the other, but other times you may go back and forth between debugging and breaking it down.

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

### Grab a pen and paper

This can help you sort out all sorts of problems, from the logic of an algorithm you need to write, to the design of a system, to understanding code you found somewhere, to figuring out why your code isn't working.

Some ideas for what you can write down:

- What will happen at each step in your code
- How each variable changes on each line
- A graph (e.g. [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)) containing all the parts you think you'll need, where you can connect different parts, add more details to each part and maybe add or remove parts
- The values of each parameter (and all local variables) for each step of a recursive function call
- In case of needing to write an algorithm, how you'll solve the problem by hand

Some of these can also be done with a debugger or using specialised tools, although, if you're not familiar with such things, a simple pen and paper can be an easier starting point. You can also use a debugger *in addition* to a pen and paper, to write down what you find with the debugger.

### Search (a lot, but more than that)

Type your question into Google.

Then try to think of another way to phrase your question and type that into Google.

Then repeat that a few more times.

Click on every link which even hasn't the smallest chance of answering your question. Spend some time reading every page that seems promising, even if it seems slightly different to your issue or you're having some trouble understanding it.

You should even go to, dare I say, "page 2" of the search results.

**Google the final title of your post** (and the actual question in the body of your post) - the phrasing you use may change in the process of writing the question, so make sure you actually type that final title and question into Google as a last sanity check before posting your question. It's pretty damning if someone else can easily find an answer to your question by simply throwing your title into Google.

### Check the docs and look for code samples

If your program includes a library function or class that might not be working as expected, you should definitely look up the function in the relevant official docs to see whether you're understanding what it's supposed to do correctly, and whether there's maybe an example to help you.

Searching may lead you there, but, if it doesn't, you should make an effort to specifically go there.

### Go through a tutorial or read a book

Yes, this might seem like overkill if you just want to solve some small issue, but many times one small issue points to a more fundamental lack of understanding, so we might not be able to explain how to solve the issue sufficiently well for you to understand and/or you may have many more small issues in future which would've all been solved by going through a tutorial or book.

### Rule of thumb

You should spend at least an hour on the above, or maybe a few hours (or less if you find the answer that way).

### See also:

[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 4):

I have to first of all thank you for thinking of research before asking a question, most people don't do that. Most people like yourself when researching program problems aren’t sure where to start, but you might be able to find great insight into your problem in places that are commonly over-looked.

**Tips to research**:

*Google it*: google is a tool most of us can’t live without, it provides quick searches to thousands of websites

*Use Stack Overflow*: Stack Overflow might not have your question, but it most likely has questions that are relevant to your question. (type in the tag of the language then search away)

*Use the manual*: every programming language out there has some type of manual, these manuals can give you examples, insights, and explanations.

*Use the chat room*: I will always ask a question in the chat room to see how it might be received, chat rooms are friendly and full of helpful people (**Please follow the chat rooms rules**).

Even if you might get the answer you are looking for it’s still helpful to the community to post your question even if you end up answering it yourself.

Every time you ask a question you are able to compare it to similar questions on Stack Overflow, just make sure that the topics don't match up to much.

Comment: Doesn't your question just get overlooked like all the comments in a livestream on Twitch?

Comment: On Twitch? I'm talking about the Stack Overflow chat rooms. 
  https://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yeah I know what you're talking about. I meant that the comments in the chatroom would just get overlooked wouldn't they?

Comment: I've never had that problem before. what language is your question in?

Comment: I'm not having a question yet..oh well actually I have one that's why I'm chilling on SO for the last 3 hours. It's ASP.NET MVC using DevExtreme. But I don't feel like it's worth someone else's time  I just have to research it by myself.

Comment: Someone in the chat rooms could probably give you some good tips on that and if they can't they'll be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Alright I am going to check those chatrooms out. Thanks for your input and help. It's highly appreciated:)

Comment: However don't abuse chatrooms for asking (too many) questions...

Comment: I'd also add Wikipedia. If you know the name of the thing you're trying to do, there's a very good chance Wikipedia knows about it; for algorithms, it almost certainly has mathematical and/or pseudocode representation, and very often also an implementation in one or several popular programming languages.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using chat rooms to "test" your question. If you have a good on-topic question that doesn't have an answer elsewhere, you should be asking it on the main site so it can help others too. If you ask in chat, it'll get ignored, which doesn't help anyone, or answered, which doesn't help anyone *else* (few would ask their question on the main site after they've already gotten an answer). I'd say you should only really ask things that aren't on topic on the main site in chat rooms.

Comment: Chat rooms have *some* tolerance for helping newbies out. If the room gets drowned in newbie FAQs it stops working and you drive away the regulars; so use it sparingly. But oftentimes, the regulars will be happy to help you get started on a specific topic if you can explain what exactly you need help with, even if it's a FAQ. (But obviously, don't ask about Python in a C room, or about Windows in a Linux room.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is interesting, because its premise is that if the answer wasn't found on Stack Overflow, then it must have been found on some other website otherwise it couldn't exist. But you are forgetting the key salient point that's at the core of our jobs: *the knowledge had to come from a person, first*.

And what you're seeing, more often than not, is knowledge coming straight from a person.

How can a user write an answer to a question? How can they know the answer if the asker didn't know?

**Experience.**

It's all about experience. Either the answerer already knows the answer from previous encounters with the same problem, or they worked it out using their finely-honed critical thinking and logical deduction skills (again, *experience*!) or they indeed just found it someplace else with their enhanced research abilities (which grow with *experience*).

All you're doing when you ask a question on Stack Overflow is borrowing the brain of somebody who has more *experience* than you in some domain, be it technical or mental.

Well, and then there's just the silly stuff where you forgot something simple and it needed another person to come along and point out your mistake. However, most of the time those are "bad questions" because you should have been able to figure it out yourself with a bit of rest and perhaps some duck programming. Again, *experience* teaches us when this technique will be useful.

If I were to be unwelcoming I'd also talk briefly about the category of questions which are honestly just lazy, where the answer was already readily available in some documentation or even right there in the compiler error, but the OP did not put in the work to perform the research. In this case, what applies is the *experience* to know when this level of laziness won't go down well with those around you, and you need to go spend more time on the problem on your own.