# Problem asking/searching questions

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, duplicate-questions, search

I have been on Stack Overflow for a while, and I always search for the question I have before asking it. However, sometimes I don't find it, I ask it, and it results in a downvoted question because it's duplicated. Now I'm facing the risk of being blocked, and mainly for two reasons:

1. My search didn't have the "rights" terms/tags in order to find the question I'm looking for (while I struggled to think how different I could ask the question).
2. I didn't know the exact terms of the question already answered (and sometimes they are not "common" tags).

So, any tips to avoid being blocked?

Comment: If you are using Stack Overflow search to try find duplicates beforehand, that's a major stumbling block; use Google. It'll 95% of the time send you straight back to a Stack Overflow answer, but it's much easier to get your search right.

Comment: "Write the code for me" questions like "float to integer python" rarely get any warm welcome... and no, "How can I implement this conversion in a succinct and safe way" does not read as "I tried this and that approaches" but rather - "give me teh codez". Consider reading through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and also search meta for "demonstrated research" to see how one is expected to *demonstrate* research in the question.

Comment: If you haven't found it yet, you might like the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Duplicates don't endanger your account, I don't believe. Downvoted and deleted questions do. Your question list looks pretty good, since you have lots of upvoted questions compared to downvoted ones. SO isn't a good place for extremely basic syntax questions, as these exist in a layer of chaos which may result in them gaining lots of upvotes or lots of downvotes. But be warned, the chance of upvotes is much less than downvotes. Better to buy a book on python syntax and read it than to ask questions about the subject.

Comment: Google: `my question about vague topic xyz site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I ask it, and it results in a downvoted question because it's duplicated.

Asking a duplicate question is never an issue nor a reason to get downvotes. There is a lot of duplicate questions that get upvoted because they are well written and well explained. Finding a duplicate isn't always trivial and easy.

So if your question is well asked<sup>1</sup> and you really did a research effort<sup>2</sup> before asking then there is no reason to get downvotes even if it get closed as duplicate.

---

<sup>1</sup>  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

<sup>2</sup> If for example I can find the answer by googling your title or some of your content then I can conclude that you have done 0 effort and you may *probably* deserve a downvote.

---

If I take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662258/what-means-the-comma-in-matplotlib-python) as an example and I google your title I will get [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%20means%20the%20comma%20in%20matplotlib%20site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0tf79lKjfAhUDJlAKHYDRDjYQrQIoBDAAegQIBxAO&biw=1600&bih=740) and the second question seems to be pretty close: [matplotlib 2d line line,=plot comma meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742765/matplotlib-2d-line-line-plot-comma-meaning). This at some degree explain the downvotes you got.

So first ask google the same question you would ask on stackoverflow and don't stick to the first result. Spend few minutes checking all the links and go to the second and even the third result page. You have a good chance to find what you need.

If you get nothing then get back to (1) and write a good question. Here also you should take the needed time to write the question.

**What you should avoid**

1. Let me Google this.
2. Checking the first link. *(Not what I want)*
3. Let me ask a question. *(Taking 5 min to write it)*
4. downvotes, closes votes ...

**What you should do**

1. Let me Google this.
2. Checking many links (SO and not SO).
3. Reading all the answers, comments, following related links.
4. Get back to (1) and try different keywords. *(probably 5 or 6 times, even 10 times!)*
5. Still nothing, let me ask a question.
6. While writing, I am getting related questions, let me check them.
7. Updating the quesiton, reading it again, fixing mistakes.
8. Let me have another Google try.
9. Still nothing. Reading my question again, adding tags.
10. hit the ask question button!

You may probably never reach (10) and you will get your answer before.

Comment: As I've often said on Meta: I keep my personal questions in draft for 7 days... yes, **7 days**. By the end of that week, you either have a **very** polished question, or you just fix your issue yourself.

Comment: 2 or 3? 20 or 30.

Comment: @philipxy well, 2/3 is somehow low but I think the overal idea is clear ;) .. let's increase it a little

Answer (score 8):

The first thing is to ensure that you use Google search for your questions. There have been debates about SO's own search engine and, like SEDE, it's maybe one of those things you can master. Outside of that, just use Google.

I'm only familiar with Python, not R, so I looked at your last 3 duped questions. The intention is *not* to pull some Meta effect on you so I'm only giving the titles as illustrations. Here's how I would either a) Google the problem to solve it or B) Google the problem to dupe your question:

1. "Increasing the h-size of plots in plt.subplot() inside a loop - Python [duplicate]" -- > Search term: "matplotlib wider figure" --> Auto-suggested search: "matplotlib make figure wider" --> [your dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)
2. "Conditional replacing - Python [duplicate]" --> Search term: "pandas replace value with nan". [New dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097236/how-to-replace-values-with-none-in-pandas-data-frame-in-python) and a perfect illustration; OK, so the replaced value, *and* the replacement value don't match yours, but the method itself is perfectly applicable. Next search is just how to find out how to define NaN.
3. "What means the comma in matplotlib? - python [duplicate]" --> search term: "why matplotlib plot comma" --> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742765/matplotlib-2d-line-line-plot-comma-meaning). In this case, I know a much better dupe and a better way to search for it, but even the caveman search string is pulling up results that explain the functioning.

In case 3, I'd be jumping straight for a dupe. 1 and 2, I'd think you could at least have done a bit more research. Perhaps you need to detach yourself from the specific problem a little in your searches and literally just boil it down to caveman language of tasks.