# How do I make my question better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Why do for loops seem non-sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266946/why-do-for-loops-seem-non-sequential)*

What can I change about it to make it better?

Comment: For one, don't rely on an external link.

Comment: Show the HTML you expect and show the HTML you’re getting.

Comment: "*(inspect element for problem)*" no, don't say that. Instead give a [mcve] of that problem. The code on that website can change at any point, or it might go down, so the question now becomes worthless for any future readers.

Comment: Coming back to this tab and now I notice that what was supposed to be a magic link wasn't actually formatted correctly - [mcve] is supposed to automatically make a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you see and use the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)? It helps in self-evaluating your question. There is also  guidance on [this externally maintained website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) which you might find useful.

Answer (score 4):

Your minimal example (the code in the question) isn't self-contained - it can't run in isolation.

Your self-contained example (the code in the link) doesn't look to be minimal - and at present it's struck through saying "website was changed" which makes it really unclear (should I be looking at it? If yes, why is it struck through? If not, why hasn't it just been deleted?)

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways that you can improve your questions. Here are a few:

- Add your code so that what you are asking is clearer to understand
- Make your question specific and ask EXACTLY what you are trying to find out
- Tell the users what you want to be accomplished
- Say what kind of things you already tried
- If applicable, show any error messages