# What does the wording means "This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

Tags: discussion

What does these wording means "This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

Example: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137369/why-gethashcode-is-called?noredirect=1#comment108158533_61137369)

Comment: That question was closed because it needs more detail to people be able to answer the question. Specifically, you need to show how queryCommonFiles is defined. Without that detail people can only guess. Incidentally I guess queryCommonFiles is an enumerable got from comparing the files on two different folders, that comparison requires an implementation of IEqualityComparer, and because that enumerable is lazy, the comparison is only done when enumerating the enumerable. The method Any() starts enumerating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question got closed because it needs details.

Specially it needs a complete reproducible example as code in the question, instead of a screenshot of your code.

Even the answer you got admits it takes a guess (a well educated guess) at what is causing the behavior you observed. Don't make it so that users (either those that you expect help from or future visitors) have to fantasize about the code you show them. There is no need to have a guess at it.

When you improve your question to add the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it lacks, your question will go to the re-open queue and if that edit was valuable enough users might chose to re-open your question.

Also worth reading is [this site](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: How does a user know if and when their closed question will be re-reviewed? How will they know if it has sufficient details or not?

Comment: @Cherona well, if the Help Centre didn't provide enough guidance they can use the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and/or the [guidance on this site](https://idownvotedbecau.se/) to get an idea what enough is. When that editing is done, they can watch the timeline of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62247560/timeline) to see if it gets into the re-open queue and how those reviews progress.