# Why my questions immediately getting Downvotes? How to improve?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

So below is a question I asked recently.
[How to check nil for a property already forcefully downcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385543/how-to-check-nil-for-a-property-already-forcefully-downcasts).

It is a problem I faced while doing a project. So I searched in google just like I always do, but somehow I couldn't find a proper answer. So I decided to create a question in SO.
Immediately after I created the question I got downvoted. I know when you ask a question in SO you have to generalise it as much as possible. So I did. But still, I couldn't figure out how to ask a question without getting downvoted. My questions are beginner-level so some might think that I am dumb.

But SO is usually used by beginners and intermediate coders. I wouldn't mind getting flagged for a duplicate but downvoting without a reason seems sad. At least these people could comment on the reason. So what is my problem and how to Improve?

Comment: Duplicate questions are often evaluated in terms of *how useful they are to the site as duplicates* (i.e., to help people who have the same question to find the correct Q&A), rather than simply on their own merits.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not a Swift developer so I can't tell if there is something *technically* wrong with your question but there is one thing that stands out in your Meta confession, and that is this:

> So I searched in google just like I always do, but somehow I couldn't find a proper answer.

That might be true but you didn't include what you searched for nor which possible solutions you applied. That is what we mean when we say [*show your research*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It becomes even more relevant if plugging your error in [Stack Overflows own search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Initializer+for+conditional+binding+must+have+Optional+type%2C+not+%27String%27&mixed=0) I get  68 results. I find it hard to believe that if you tried a couple of those you wouldn't have got different error messages.

By including what you searched for and which posts you picked and tried is helpful for the volunteers that offer their free-time to solve the presented problem because instead of wondering *which of those 68 posts did they already tried* they can switch to "ah, that is not how it is called" or "Yeah, that seems logical but that is not the root cause here" or "no, that is indeed confusing in the documentation" ... you get the idea.

See also: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)
and the [Question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as well as [this external site with tips](https://idownvotedbecau.se/).