# Can someone help me improve my own question and fix the mess I made?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I apologize; I made several mistakes. Here are some, but not all:
I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64632467/redirectmatch-how-to-match-any-words-but-not-index-and-nothing) that I could probably have answered on my own after some research and test, although the help I received helped me a lot; I answered my question by proving this. I thought it was helpful, sorry. I was also wrong by leaving the real website in the code example, sorry again.

The community first closed it and then reopened it and evaluated both the question and the answer negatively so I tried to improve it and finally to delete it, but having received a second answer and also having received some positive votes I could not do it.

I asked for removal via flags, and here's another error, sorry.

Thanks to those who voted negatively, because I was able to learn things I did not know about how this site works, although I would have appreciated a comment.

Now I ask myself: since we try to have only high quality questions and answers, what is the balance between removing a low quality question by losing a few points to those who have spent time and keeping it by giving up on having a site of high quality?

Finally, since I don't like having made these mistakes, is there anything else I can do to fix this mess? If there is nothing to do, the only option is to ask to remove my nickname from the posts?

Now I'm a little scared to do anything so after reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa). I asked here but if I was wrong, I apologize in advance

Comment: Your overall score i.e. the sum of votes on all your questions is positive so there's really nothing to panic about a single problem question.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I lose a few points, it doesn't seem like a good thing to keep a low quality question. I tried to remove it yesterday but it wouldn't let me do.

Comment: Did you try to unaccept your own answer and then delete the question?

Comment: *...but having received a second answer and also having received some positive votes I could not do it.* But isn't the second answer yours?

Comment: @rene I tried to delete it after unaccept my own answer, but I can't delete it, probably due to one positive vote that question has received.

Comment: @RobertLongson that remaining answer has an upvote and will block deletion.

Comment: Tried but I can't do it

Comment: In theory we could downvote the question to -3 and then delete vote ... or down vote the answer and delete vote but given that both the question and the answer got an upvote I don't think I want to participate in that. I think the question looks fine and so does the answer but I'm not into apache mod-rewrite and its regex at all.

Comment: Ahh OK. Well in that case it's probably best to restore your answer and move on. After all it's only one question.

Comment: @BSMP one answer was mine (now is deleted) and the second is another user

Comment: @RobertLongson I restore it, so nothing to do here?

Comment: Someone who is an expert in the technology of the question may come along and comment on how you could improve your question.

Comment: "it doesn't seem like a good thing to keep a low quality question", I am not an expert in the domain, but your question doesn't seem low quality.  If anything, it's a testament to tenacity and shows that the edit and re-open process works.  You have code, you have an explanation of what you tried and what didn't work and what the expected outcome is.  Don't let downvotes get you down.  As long as you keep putting effort into your questions, you're doing fine.  Also, don't let closed-as-duplicate get you down either, good duplicates are still good.

Comment: @zero298 thanks, I appreciated and understood your positive feedback, I will keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Deleting posts will put your profile in a worse state.

That question went through so many stages, it was edited 9 times, it was closed once and reopened once. That brings plenty of users to a post.

I'm not a subject matter expert but I see not much wrong with the question in the current revision. Nor do I think the answers are useless.

That they picked up downvotes is unfortunate but none of the content in that Q/A pair seems to be a total train wreck at this moment in time.

You can't delete questions once you have an answer with an upvote and moderators are not going to delete answers only because you want the question to be deleted. I assume you asked in good faith but there are so many abuse vectors if mods would delete answers like that, we better refrain from asking that from them.

Just move on. Next time think and [research](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) twice before you tag a question with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)

See also: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: thanks, yes, I edited many times to try to improve it, but without success. Next time I'll think twenty times before post a question :)

Comment: Yes, most of the new questions that have been tagged with the regex tag seem to have lots of downvotes.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy and rightfully so. The followers of that tag spend much time to guide new askers in the tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: @rene Maybe we should instate a limit that doesn't allow new users to ask questions with that tag; I think we should stop letting new users litter that tag with low-quality closed questions.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy I imagine Questions without the tag, but with "regex" in the title.

Comment: thanks for all, and thanks for spending time to create a better place. Now, after further reading, I've learned that I've to think two thousand time before ask a question here, but this is good.

Comment: @Scratte Well, not having the regex tag would still make a bad question receive downvotes, since whether or not the tag is in there doesn't actually influence whether or not the question gets downvotes; it's probably just that the low-quality questions happened to have the regex tag. Nevertheless, the regex tag has a whole lot of low-quality questions.

Comment: I am the *other guy* who dared to answer on OP's question and still believe I have the right answer :) (due to my long experience with regex and .htaccess problems). Anyway It is OP's prerogative to chose whatever works best for him/her.

Comment: Your answer is spot on for the issue raised by @Lety. Except that I am not in agreement with last sentence `Next time think twice before you tag a question with regex`. IMO if your problem or solution needs use of regex then do feel free to use this tag and fear no one. It is quality of question that gets upvoted/downvoted not a relevant tag. SO allows up to 5 tags so that we can chose all relevant ones for a post.

Comment: I tagged my question with `[regex]` and now I have _two_ problems.

Comment: I have often found that the process of doing my homework to create a well-researched question ends up finding me a solution. And I'm glad I didn't actually post the question. Once, maybe, IIRC, I turned that into a kind of "Maybe others have the same misunderstanding" question and immediately answered it myself.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place to talk about the answers, but I would like to tell  @anubhava that although both answers work, I have chosen my answer for what I have read here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html, but I am ready to change my mind if I get a technical explanation that reasons why the Apache manual is wrong.