# Why was my question on Stack Overflow on the usage of existing DLLs closed?

Tags: support, languages

I only got the hint:
"Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving."

Which details? I described the problem to the best of my ability. The best hint I got from the comments was that my understanding of the English language might be extremely bad.

I.e.: I was under the impression that the word "spam" could apply to describe any situation of "unwanted contents", not just emails. As as far as I know that use itself was derived from an abundance of a canned meat product called "spam".

I am not a native English speaker, so I need to assume if someone feels the need to leave such a comment I might have offended someone with that ignorant misuse of "spam" (or am talking nearly incomprehensible gibberish). With my current lack of information, other than the fact that my post seems to be incomprehensible to Stack Overflow users, I am left to wild guesses as to why my question was closed. I can only assume that I committed some type of blunder I am not aware of. Probably due to my lack of real cultural experiences within the English language.

Closed question:
*[Use already built/old DLL files in a Visual Studio 2019 C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358247/use-already-build-old-dll-files-visual-studio-2019-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment115548121_65358247)*

Or was the link to SourceForge some type of tabu? (Advertising? Bad reputation of the author of the linked project?)

Did I use too informal language?

Comment: I went ahead and moved this for you. :) As a note, other than your need for a bit of capitalization, your English seems perfectly serviceable. I'm sorry that you got the impression that it was poor... also, while it may be someone's pet peeve, I think "spam" is regularly used the way you did, so I'm not sure why they found fault in it.

Comment: Relevant: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/11682469)

Comment: Like the "Not an Answer" flag, the term "spam" is regularly co-opted beyond its original meaning, and I stand by my decision to comment on it.  Even [the most liberal definitions of the word](https://www.google.com/search?q=spam+definition) clearly specify that it is about "messages," which really doesn't have much to do with copying DLL's from one place to another.

Comment: In any case, the question being discussed here is unanswerable in its present form.  I'm not really sure what sort of clarification could be provided, other than to upload the entire project to some site for everyone to look at.  Please don't do that, though; Stack Overflow isn't set up for that sort of thing.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Thank you for the clarification. On the spam comment. Now i can at least understand your position. Seriously, i often get upset at something for the same reason.

Comment: I'm not upset, just concerned.  Programming demands a level of precision that is not always required by other occupations.

Comment: I cleaned up the few grammatical and other errors in the English. As @Catija mentioned, that wasn't the problem. The issue is that the question is somewhat rambling; a lot of text but not a lot of meaningful sentences. For instance, after reading the whole thing, all I know is that you're trying to build a project with references to DLLs (?) and you may or may not be having an issue with versioning. We like to see error messages and links to other SO questions you've tried that haven't worked. Details.

Comment: Heretic Monkey, that is something i can work with.
I Still need to get used to the auto submit on "enter".
How should i handle this: Edit the original post or make a new one?

Comment: Robert Harvey  As mentioned English is not my native language. I assumed "upset" to be on the very low end of that scale. I only intended to communicate that i do infact understand your position and agree on the principle. But not the specific example. Further clarification: In my opinion pretending that i now agree with your comment on spam would just be dishonesty too avoid conflict which i find disrepectful. But i can fully identify with how you phrased that last sentence: "Programming demands a level of precision that is not always required by other occupations."

Comment: Definitely edit the old one @daniel, don't open a new question with the same content when the old one can still be salvaged.

Comment: @daniel - Tools to verify your spelling and grammar exist.  While those tools are not perfect in the case of properly spelled words which are actually the incorrect word you can often get to a 90% solution.

Answer (score 19):

Because it's a poor question, not just by Stack Overflow's standards but objectively.

Here's an exercise for you: pretend you know **nothing** about the problem you're having, and go back and re-read what you've written in that question. I think you will then understand why it was closed as "needs details or clarity" - it's literally **impossible** for anyone to understand what you're trying to achieve, because you haven't supplied the required detail to answer it.

Stack Overflow requires **focused** questions that will attract **specific** answers. Yours is the exact opposite of focused and in its current state, simply isn't answerable.

I think you'll find that "I described the problem to the best of my ability" isn't correct. Even if it is, that isn't a get-out-of-jail-free card for writing a question that doesn't conform to this site's standards by being unanswerable.

Asking good questions is a skill that can be mastered, regardless of language; I have worked with many non-native English speakers whose English would be considered "poor", but who were quite capable of expressing problems clearly and concisely. It's almost never about language - it's almost always about communication skills, or lack thereof.

Comment: I still don't understand what is unclear about wanting to use existing builds of DLLs. I even wrote why i want to use the existing ones. I did not expect to use the language barrier as shield. I just run out of good explanations so i resorted to using "what's left". My next best guess wwould be just including links to SO questions i found during research. But that doesn't appear to be very usefull to me either.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to be incredibly blunt now: your question essentially reads like pointless rambling about what you should do in a completely hypothetical scenario. **There are no specifics whatsoever.** You have not shown or described what the **actual problem** is in terms of an actual project. You have not shown or described what you have attempted to solve the problem. Your question has zero context as to what it's trying to achieve, and that makes it unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you. This resolves my question. I could not provide the exact examples because that might leak critical information. But now i at least know that this type of content is not wanted here. I can accept that I misjudged what this site is for. (And therefore have misused it.) To be more precise: If i can't resolve the problem myself i will now know what to do to write a beter question.