# Advice on breaking down "code dumps"

Tags: support, edits

I'm newer to SO and I enjoy editing posts from time to time. A common post format I will see if something along the lines of this:

---

Hello, my question is ...

code1.file

```
MASSIVE PASTE OF CODE
```

code2.file

```
MASSIVE PASTE OF CODE
```

code3.file

```
MASSIVE PASTE OF CODE
```

---

This is quite an eyesore and generally a pain to read through 200+ lines of code. Since I didn't ask the question and don't always 100% know what is useful, how can I work with the OP to remove irrelevant code?

Comment: Thanks for assisting users in getting their question into shape. As for large code dumps it in general is a sign that the question needs details or clarity. You can flag those questions as such. You can direct users to the help center, specially the [MPR topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Alternatively walk them through the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648) or see if the guidance on [this external site](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) is useful

Comment: It can be hard to determine what is and isn't relevant without help from the asker.  Unless the question is really clear, you could focus the question on bug X when the asker was struggling with bug Y. Worse when you ask for them to post a minimal reproducible example, it seems most don't read the link and ignore the reproducible part. It's hard to wrangle askers who don't know enough about what they're trying to do to ask a good question about it. Usually I wind up recommending that the asker back up their code and try to write a smaller program that focusses on one thing. And then another...

Comment: Lots of kudos for choosing to put time into this.  I'll be honest, when I see code dumps I just move on now days.

Comment: But please don't move on without at least casting a close vote. @Taplar