# Which questions to target to reinstate asking privilege

Tags: support

I lost my privilege to ask questions and I'm trying to work on my old questions to get that re-instated.

I suspect these questions are my biggest issues:

[Why does this code compile on windows but not on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456096/why-does-this-code-compile-on-windows-but-not-on-macos)

This one was the one that pulled me over the line of the contribution check.

[Datagrid combobox selectionchanged event argument differ between two pc's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63242991/datagrid-combobox-selectionchanged-event-argument-differ-between-two-pcs)

This question has received one downvote without any explanation as to why this question is bad.

[Code not reachting the lines in code which it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626374/code-not-reachting-the-lines-in-code-which-it-should)

When posting this question I've forgotten to include a piece of recursive code. This resulted in 3 downvotes, however, after editing in the code the downvotes stayed.

Those are the only question where I received downvotes. The rest of my questions do rate an average just above 0 but have a (generous) amount of views.

Comment: Target the ones with the most downvotes and any that were deleted while <= 0.

Comment: Did you already read and applied all advice in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and  the FAQ on [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? Beyond that the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) might be useful to quick-jump to relevant background.

Comment: You can edit your most downvoted question to fix grammar and format the code properly(please indent with four spaces for readability and comment out “Stop Point Here” with “//” for easy copy-paste)

Comment: @RobertLongson That is only the first question, this was the only question I ever deleted after trying a couple of times to achieve the expected requirements. I recognize this question was posted too hastily as my knowledge of c++ is very limited and with a couple of days of studying, I could have concluded my error myself. The issue however is the older two questions that I don't see anything wrong with but I still got downvotes. Is my only option to hope that someone comes across those and upvotes those?

Comment: The system can delete questions too e.g. if the question was closed without answers and you do nothing to edit it to try to get it reopened.

Comment: You have the following 6 deleted questions: [Q1](//stackoverflow.com/q/66239443) [Q2](//stackoverflow.com/q/63776529) [Q3](//stackoverflow.com/q/59152636) [Q4](//stackoverflow.com/q/57759268) [Q5](//stackoverflow.com/q/37477280) [Q6](//stackoverflow.com/q/34391296). If you can't ask new questions, please read **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)** However, the system states that you re not *currently* blocked from asking questions, but were blocked recently.