# "How to create MRE for <Thing>" - opinion-based, community wiki, or move to meta?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

It is a rough heuristic, but when a post has many up-votes it suggests that it was valuable. If one toggles their cursor over the up-arrow button for a post, it says "*This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear*". On that basis I inferred that [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) had provided value to the SO community, and produced the post [How to make a great Python reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400747/how-to-make-a-great-python-reproducible-example) in seemingly the same [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of questions. A similar, `pandas`-oriented post called [How to make a good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) was also brought to my attention.

The question I have here is built on the discrepancy on how my post was moderated in contrast to these other two. The other two were converted to [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) posts, which are no-longer questions. Mine was closed as [opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

A comment proposed that my post would have similar answers as found in [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which would rather suggest to me that my post should have been closed as a duplicate in that sense. I think my question definitely **is** opinion-based whereas the redundancy to the earlier post is reasonable, but more debatable.

What is a consistent way of handling this discrepancy? At this point, I don't feel that my post was treated consistently with the precedent that was set by the previous `R`-based post.

Perhaps these among other options might be considered:

1. Closed as opinion-based (converting the former community wikis back into questions)
2. Convert my post into a community wiki
3. Move all three posts to meta SO

Or, perhaps a future meta-post on the *pitfalls and gotchas* of SO might be beneficial beyond the standard orientation.

What are your thoughts on how this should be resolved?

The original post has received vote(s) for deletion. I have duplicated it here for future context in case of deletion.

> Echoing a corresponding post ["*How to make a great R reproducible example*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is important that Python programmers are successful in communicating qualitative and quantitative aspects of their code. Naturally there is a use case for posting excellent examples here on Stack Overflow, but also on blogs, other Q&A sites, presentations, documentation, and code base repositories like GitHub.
>
> A few of the criterion to consider, as described in ["*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), include using examples that are (1) minimal, (2) complete, and (3) reproducible.
>
> What Python-oriented advice, tips, techniques, or criteria make a great `python` reproducible example?
>
> ##### Edit
>
> For more information on the closure of this post, see ["*Opinion-based, community wiki, or moved to meta?*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409174/opinion-based-community-wiki-or-moved-to-meta)

Comment: There is at least one metric common between the two open questions that isn't common to yours, in that they were both asked more than 7 years ago. There's also some evidence that there was collaboration between several people that resulted in each being asked/answered, potentially even a group from the tag, rather than one person

Comment: @KevinB I am sure many distinctions *can* be made. There are other equivalence relations than the identity relation. Is there a particular significance to a post being 7 years old?

Comment: Yes, millions of questions/answers have been added to the site since then. Moderation has become more strict, more questions are being asked per day, etc

Comment: @KevinB Why not retroactively apply moderation standards?

Comment: Personally i wish they would be, but posts that have been proven to be useful over time get special treatment

Comment: @KevinB You're not the first to say that. If there is will for that to be done, why isn't there a way?

Comment: I think the path to have such a question created, and be successful, would start on meta, in a chat room, somewhere other than SO. the first thing that has to be answered, is whether or not it is needed given the resource available today, then it can be expanded past that. I wouldn't expect that question to go well, if it didn't already have a great answer the moment it was posted.

Comment: @KevinB It is disappointing to hear that such inconsistency is bureaucratically protected. Thank you for weighing in on this. It is appreciated.

Comment: "when a post has many up-votes it suggests that it was valuable" at most it suggest that it's popular.

Comment: @Braiam In terms of causality, I strongly agree with that remark. The real reason that someone votes, and whether they vote up or down, is more complicated. I only mean this as a rough [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic). Nonetheless, thank you for adding nuance.

Comment: [21,481,545 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and counting.

Comment: @PeterMortensen And that's not even [counting the deleted ones](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1436072/post-type-counts).

Comment: @Galen It is infeasible to retroactively apply moderation standards for many reasons. One of those being that it would be a neverending battle and there simply isn't capacity amongst curators here for such. Another is that judging a question from N years ago as invalid by today's standards, is often as futile as judging a movie from N years ago as sexist.

Comment: @IanKemp Thank you for framing that in terms of feasibility constraints for running SO. That is an equivalence class that I care about.

Comment: Possibly the reaction could have been different if you had converted the post from the start in a community wiki.

Comment: The original question was deleted, but nothing has been done about the older questions. Shouldn't they be deleted as well then?

Comment: @Galen The point of deleting the new question is that there is no advantage to keeping it around – it doesn't have any worthwhile answers, nor can it get any. The old question in contrast already has collected valuable content, and deleting it would likely do more harm than good.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Would migration to MSO be preferable then?

Comment: Something being 'community wiki' doesn't mean it is no longer a question, it just signals it is a collaborative effort which doesn't 'belong' to the original OP (i.e. they don't get reputation for the upvotes).

Answer (score 28):

These type of posts are a poor fit for the main site, but they would be a much better fit for Meta.

They're questions about using Stack Overflow itself.  They're not practical programming problems.  Questions on Stack Overflow will never be a duplicate of them.

Moving them to Meta (or at *least* creating future ones here, though I'd vote to move the existing ones too) solves these issues.  Meta contains lots of advice for using Stack Overflow and what constitutes a good question.  Meta users are used to keeping FAQs up to date.  It's where how to use Stack Overflow is discussed.

Comment: Then they'd probably be a duplicate of [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), though

Comment: @Cerbrus That looks like a pretty poor duplicate. I don't doubt someone will vote that way anyway, but I'd be willing to challenge such a closure.

Comment: My point was that there are already plenty of resources out there that cover the subject. I'm sure there are dupes that fit even better.

Comment: At least a cursory search did not turn up anything for me. To be clear, I think the "dupe" does not fit *at all* – a checklist on general question requirements is something entirely different than a language specific guide on reducing code and presenting data.

Answer (score 11):

These type of posts are a poor fit for the main site, but they would be a much better fit for Meta.

## However,

We don't need an *"How to make a great <> reproducible example"* for every language out there.

There are enough resources available already to help you write a good question, such as ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I also agree.  Such questions should probably be required to come with a pre-written answer that justifies their existence—that is, that doesn't basically just rehash general MRE advice or that checklist, but provides useful language/framework-specific advice.  Having these as questions with no answer doesn't do a whole lot of good and risks cluttering the site for little benefit.

Comment: We don't need a post for *every* language, but having one for the *most popular* languages could be a help.  @AlexeiLevenkov for example in Python it's really easy to replace file input with a list in the program itself - and if you can't make a MRE that way then you're half way towards solving the problem on your own, and some Python-specific advice might go a long way.

Comment: No, we don't need language-specific "how to" questions, regardless of how popular the language is, or whatever other arbitrary criteria you want to apply to justify said questions. Stack Overflow is not the place to teach people how to do the most basic tasks in their language of choice, nor is it the place to attempt to teach them how to ask an answerable question in 20 million different ways. And the reason for that is not because doing so would be off-topic, but because the people who lack those skills are almost universally unwilling to learn them. **You cannot teach the will to learn.**

Comment: @MarkRansom Is Ian Kemp accurately characterizing your position on picking some languages rather than others?

Comment: If there are people out there who want to create content with language-specific instructions on creating good questions, there are venues for you; they are just not Stack Overflow. Blogging platforms abound these days. You can't swing a dead cat meme without hitting a couple dozen "content aggregation platforms" so you know as soon as you post something it will get tweeted, instabooked, tiktwitched about all you want.

Comment: @HereticMonkey In your opinion, should such questions be retroactively removed from SO?

Comment: @IanKemp if I let my failure to reach the unreachable be my guide, I would have given up on this site a very long time ago.  If we can turn but one unanswerable question into something decent through a more targeted approach to MRE, it would be worth it.  Galen, the odds of making a positive difference go up with the number of questions that would benefit from the advice.

Comment: I think the Python ecosystem is too wide-ranging for a single how-to-mre to be useful.  But maybe a better approach might be to create language-agnostic how-to-mre for specific types of question.  For example, I see a lot of beginner questions for web frameworks that include everything from html to db because the asker doesn't know how to isolate their problem to a specific layer in their app.   Perhaps how-to-mre would be useful for these, either in meta or a tag wiki (the chances of discoverability are about the same, alas).

Comment: @cerbrus You voted to delete [*How to make a great Python reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400747/how-to-make-a-great-python-reproducible-example). Are you also going to vote to delete [*How to make a great R reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [*How to make a good reproducible pandas example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Comment: That's not relevant to this answer on this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus Where is an appropriate place to ask that question then?

Comment: That was a subtle way of saying it's inappropriate to tell someone how to vote.

Comment: @Cerbrus I thought I was asking a pointed question, not a demand. But I see how you took it that way. I just want to better understand the way questions are being handled.

Comment: I'd think the answers here would provide enough information in that regard, already.

Comment: @Cerbrus The answers here illustrate some of the perspectives that exist, and that is appreciated. It is less clear to me what actions would or should follow this meta discussion.

Comment: @Galen your question is irrelevant, since both the R and pandas questions are community wiki'd and therefore - unfortunately - protected from being closed or deleted. In lieu of that I've raised a custom mod flag on both questions, but sadly doubt it will have any effect.

Answer (score 5):

The only point of having such a question on the main site is to use it as a dupe target. However, closing questions as a duplicate of "How to ask a question" is a misuse of the close vote system. Vote to close as "needs debugging details", and point users wherever you want in comments.

So there's absolutely no reason to have such an off-topic question on the main site. I don't personally think it's necessary anywhere, especially since any such question would eventually converge into the "how to create a pandas example" question. But at least on meta it would be harmless.

Comment: You voted to delete [*How to make a great Python reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400747/how-to-make-a-great-python-reproducible-example). Are you also going to vote to delete [*How to make a great R reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [*How to make a good reproducible pandas example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Comment: @Galen I'd love to, but neither are closed so I can't. I can't even downvote them because they are both locked.

Comment: Does anyone have the ability to adjudicate the unlocking of a post?

Comment: @Galen Mods can unlock posts, normally following meta consensus (but we've seen counterexamples). The linked questions are extra difficult, because they are really old, and mods can only migrate posts for 60 days. So we'd need SO staff to step in and move those questions to meta, if that were the consensus. Odds are this has been raised before (potentially multiple times), and the result was "meh". Still, this is no reason to add _new_ off-topic meta questions to the main site.

Comment: Is it a personal judgement by a mod if meta consensus is reached, or is there a defined process or procedure?

Comment: @Galen no idea. Considering how mods have locked/unlocked posts on a whim, I'd be surprised if there were proper protocol for this.