# Add a tag warning for [r]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-tips

I propose a tag warning for [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), specifically pointing users to an R-Specific "How to Ask", to help with minimizing the curation efforts and providing a better on-boarding experience for new users.

One of the most common close reasons for questions in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) is lack of a minimal reproducible example. Looking at the comments under questions tagged with [r], we can see that [the word "reproducible" has been used over 47,000 times](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1782407/search-comments-by-tags-and-a-keyword?CommentText=reproducible&TagID=4452) (this does not include deleted questions and comments that were removed later on). While this does not necessarily translate to all of those questions (~10% of [r] questions) lacking an MRE, it does signify the importance of it.

Here, I have provided a first draft for the tag warning:

> **Ensure your R question contains:**
>
> - Usable sample data (not just pictures) such as with `dput` function
> - The code that isn't working (including the errors, unexpected results, etc.)
> - Your desired output
> - For more information, refer to [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)

This is how it will appear when asking a question tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r):
[image: R Tag Warning]

or using the Ask Wizard:

[image: R Tag Warning variant]

Please share your thoughts about this `feature-request` in general and ideas on how the tag warning content can be improved.

---

<sub>I am the original author of the article linked in the tag warning; however, I had it disassociated from my account to avoid getting any reputation from it.</sub>

Comment: *"One of the most common close reasons for questions in [[tag:r]] is lack of a minimal reproducible example"* That likely isn't unique to just [[tag:r]]. The asking wizard, and staging ground, are much better solutions to this. The SG, however, appears to be have abandoned...

Comment: *"That likely isn't unique to just [r]"*... well, if we do the same query for [c] and even add up comments including MRE and MCVE we'll get less than 20,000 comments, that is below 5% of all questions. I agree that lacking MRE is not a unique problem, but often in [r] adding the MRE is as easy as running and providing the output of `dput(my_dataset)`. I do not see asking wizard providing any value in that regard, at least in its current format/state; while I agree that Staging Ground is a great concept for increasing qualify of questions, but something far in the future, if ever materialized.

Comment: *"but something far in the future"* That's the silly thing, the product *was* in a great state when the 2nd beta finished, and it's [*still*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRxT0.png) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground). If [so] actually have someone a day or two to finish it off, it could probably go Live... It was very well received by the testers, and *a lot* of the work to fix problems was done during the test. I just don't see the benefit of an [[tag:r]] specific solution to a problem that's site wide, and *has* a solution that's just sitting there waiting.

Comment: I mean, it's no secret that the staging ground was sidelined for OverflowAI.

Comment: I don't see anything in this tag warning that should be specific to R

Comment: "well, if we do the same query for [c] and even add up comments including MRE and MCVE we'll get less than 20,000 comments, that is below 5% of all questions" - IMX, that's because experts in the [c] tag have a considerably lower than average understanding of how the site is supposed to work, and shrug off "easy"/"homework" questions *because they are that*, rather than because of anything to do with actual reasons to close a question... and then they don't close questions that *do* meet the closure criteria... and then a lot of the time they write answers anyway, and then complain about it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What about [javascript]? the query result(s) for that would amount to even less than 1-2% of all questions. Or your tag [python]; again, less than 5%. I personally would avoid portraying a community as having lower understanding of the site... that single query is not enough evidence to draw any sort of conclusion, and in the past I've been proven wrong when relying on my personal experience more than I should have. Cheers.

Comment: @KevinB the link is definitely specific to R :) And there is not a requirement for the tag warnings to be exclusively specific to a technology, AFAIK. Take SQL tag warning, while it says that users should specify the engine and whatnot, it can be condensed to "provide an MCVE".

Comment: @M-- Fair observation that this doesn't give me proper evidence; but I *do* feel that way about the tag based on personal interactions. If the [r] tag specifically has a culture of demanding MREs then it's worth investigating why. They might have something to teach everyone else. On the other hand, it's not always a good thing - since pure "how-to" questions are perfectly acceptable, and often made worse by adding code for a failing approach.

Comment: The difference between the SQL warning and this is that the SQL warning is very specific to SQL and it is a very small thing to have to provide. It is easy and people doing SQL will know instantly what it is referring to. the MCVE request is not R-specific, it would be relevant for quite a lot of questions and it represents a lot of effort and knowledge. And because it would be shown all the time... it will become just as hated and invisible as any other nag message the modern web throws at people. Just another cookie acceptance request. Messages should be an exceptional and rare thing.

Comment: The R tag gets a lot of questions from non-programmers. Most of these are students or researchers who are at an early stage of learning R for a data science course or who are using it for statistical analysis. Many of the questions are about data manipulation which simply cannot be answered without an MRE, because the solution is entirely dependent on the structure of their data. To be honest, the quality of these questions is generally pretty poor, and though we ask for an MRE in the comments, my guess is even if they contained one, they would be closed for other reasons anyway.

Comment: I don't know if you're aware of this, but compiled Progress/ABL source code (`*.p` and `*.w` files) also have `r` as extension (`*.r` files).

Comment: @Gimby No, it is not very specific to SQL; again, it's very much asks for an MRE/MCVE. And what I included (dput) is also very small thing.

Comment: There are meta questions re how to ask a good debugging questions for specific languages & in general. There are main & meta questions re basics of optimization & other specifics. Ask, edit and/or answer Q&A for these as needed & reference as appropriate. The only way you can get people to read is in response to specific feedback about what is impeding them at the moment.

Comment: Fix the documentation & onboarding for the SITE not one tag.

Comment: I like this idea! I like the idea of warning users in multiple places. A tag warning wouldn't replace documentation elsewhere or something like the staging ground. It'd just be an extra chance to remind people who may have skimmed the documentation. I agree that a lot of this isn't R specific, but to me that's not an argument against doing it. Rather I see it as more of an argument for python and C and whoever to come up with their own similar tag warnings :D   I agree that improving SO documentation and making it more visible are important, but I don't see a cost to adding this to that.

Comment: I realize that a super long tag warning isn't ideal, but I'm wondering if a link to SO sitewide documentation for asking questions might also be helpful to add to the tag warning? And maybe a link  to dput()'s documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tag warning is in place, effective today.

Comment: Who can add such a warning for other tags as well (reputation based, mods, gold tag holders, staff, ...)? Assuming these people have access to change/add such warnings, where can the warning be changed?

Comment: @Progman Only staff can set, change or remove tag warnings.

Answer (score 14):

Getting new users to read the Help Center documentation is a problem across *all* tags, not just R. For example, when I checked a little while ago, there have been 25 questions closed in the last hour (I was actually expecting a bit more). The most common tags for those appeared to be JavaScript and Python; none of them were R questions, where the most recent closure occurred 3 hours ago. Granted, that probably reflects the fact that those languages are so widely used, but the point still remains that low-quality questions are a site-wide problem, not just specific to one tag.

The points you cite are already largely covered in [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), so again, the real issue is how to get new users to read the documentation before they post. In a perfect world, every new user would read the site tour, How to Ask, the on-topic guide, the Don't Ask page, the MRE documentation, the FAQ on why not to upload pictures of code/data/errors, How to Answer, and the Question Checklist, but we all know that most users don't. (I admittedly didn't either).

Comment: Thank you. These are all valid points (almost all, see the last sentence). But I am still not convinced that a tag warning needs to be "exclusively specific" to a technology (I have not seen that requirement on MSE). Another point about the closed questions in the last hour. The traffic between tags is not comparable so unless we do these comparisons for longer durations and based on proportions, they won't give us much valid insight. Cheers.

Comment: And you forgot to mention the Tag Wiki of the ProgLang a Question is about... (Applies to [r] but also to all other ProgLangs on 'SO'...) // If only Tag Wikis were more "discoverable" on 'SO' (instead of being kind of hidden behind some vague "_Learn more..._" Link, :shrug:...), as most of them contain perfect instructions on how to ask "Good Questions" in the Tag... (at least for all _major_ ProgLangs...)

Answer (score -2):

To those saying that nothing about the proposed warning is specific to R questions -- what is (relatively) specific is the need for sample *data.* Even if users do include their code, it's often impossible to diagnose the problem, and difficult to test / demonstrate solutions, without relevant data. In my own subjective view, failing to include sample data is a bigger issue in the [r] tag than not including code.

Obviously this isn't *unique* to R and may apply to other data science-y languages like Python or SQL. But it's still specific enough of a concern that it's not addressed by the Ask Wizard, [SO question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [[mre]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). All four of these mention including *code,* but none of them says anything about *data.* So a tag-specific warning emphasizing the need for sample data seems warranted.

Comment: That data/initialization is required in every MRE should always be mentioned & as usual the site documentation is poor & should be improved. Nothing specific to R though.

Comment: While your concern re the wording in the help centre is valid, the fundamental problem is that (a) the majority of askers don't read the help centre (b) the subset of askers who post questions lacking enough information (code, data, whatever) to answer them is a subset of the first group. Better documentation has never solved a fundamental lack of literacy.